# How can I scale an entire web page with CSS?

Tags: html, css, resize

Using Firefox, you can enlarge an entire web page by simply pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>. What this does is proportionally enlarge the entire web page (fonts, images, etc).

How can I replicate the same functionality using simply CSS?

Is there something like `page-size: 150%` (which would increase the entire page portions by x%?)

Comment: The page zoom feature of Firefox appears in every modern browser - replicating it seems rather pointless.

Comment: I agree with David.  It seems kind of pointless to replicate this since browsers now days have this feature built in....

Comment: this would actually be an incredibly useful feature for mobile devices. Lots of phones are now increasing their PPI without accommodating the difference (aside from the iPhone4, of course).

Comment: Its not replicating it. It might be useful for something like a page/element preview in an embedded div.

Comment: The page designer ought to be able to set a default zoom for his page. I have a page that was big when I made it, but small now due to high resolution displays: http://www.lonniebest.com/CardTrick/ Instead of remaking the page, I would like to be zoomed by default.

Comment: Not a complete fix, but use em's as your unit of measure. Things start to scale relative to their parent (change the body's size and everything just flows through). For more *interesting* results... use cm as your unit of measure though mobile devices seem to cut the size in half.

Answer (score 218):

You might be able to use the CSS `zoom` property - supported in IE 5.5+, Opera, and Safari 4, and Chrome

[Can I use: css Zoom](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom)

Firefox is the only major browser that does not support Zoom ([bugzilla item here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390936)) but you could use the ["proprietary" -moz-transform property in Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/CSS_transform_functions#scale).

So you could use:

```
div.zoomed { 
    zoom: 3; 
    -moz-transform: scale(3); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: The proprietary zoom property is supported only by IE. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom#compatibilitysection

Comment: David, that reference is very out of date - look at the the browser versions it lists. CSS Zoom is supported in all current major browsers except Firefox. And it's no more proprietary than any of the -moz- CSS extensions.

Comment: Note: I think the other solutions that have been proposed - such as em and % based scaling - are more "pure" but aren't necessarily practical on most web layouts unless you've built that way from scratch.

Comment: I've tested Opera 10b2 and it doesn't seem to support it. Firefox nightly behaves oddly (zoomed fragment disappears). IE5/6 are buggy. Works fine in WebKit only.

Comment: I can't argue with that thorough test suite, @porneL. You tested two obsolete versions of IE, didn't mention which Firefox you tested... I tested in all current browsers. Try it.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Opera 10.10, worked in current versions of the other four major browsers. I used `body { zoom: 0.6667; -moz-transform: scale(0.6667); }`

Comment: thanks jon, great info!

in firefox -moz-transform scale indeed works, but depending on your use case you might need to correct the position of the element using -moz-transform-origin (cfr. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform-origin)

Comment: Does not work in Opera (v11.51 on Windows; v11.50 on Linux), but "works" with everything else I tried - IE8 screws up center aligned block. Firefox is rather glitchy, sometimes adds borders and doesn't center correctly (also needed `-moz-transform-origin: center top;` to stop page being vertically centered).

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like `transform:scale` is supported by all the browser engines now (there are `-webkit-` `-moz-` `-o-` and `-ms-` prefixes).

Assuming those actually work (seem to from quick test), then the only reason to use `zoom` is for IE8 and below?

Comment: I like this solution, but I noticed that using it messes with jqplot's highlighter and zoom capabilities. Is there a solution that coordinates well with these functions?

Comment: Beware, using scale transforms can cause problems with js based/pixelbased interaction types such as draggable and order. I'm working on a similar issue and have thusfar noticed some of those still work just fine when using em units, but not with scale transforms.

Answer (score 113):

This is a rather late answer, but you can use

```
body {
   transform: scale(1.1);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   // add prefixed versions too.
}
```

to zoom the page by 110%.
Although the `zoom` style is there, Firefox still does not support it sadly.

Also, this is slightly different than your zoom. The `css transform` works like an image zoom, so it will enlarge your page but not cause reflow, etc.

---

**Edit** updated the transform origin.

Comment: Thanks for this, but you need some semicolons between the declarations.

Also, when I tried this the page shifted left, past the left margin, so that the left part of the page was no longer visible. Adding the various corresponding "...transform-origin: 0 0" declarations fixed that.

Comment: yes, I should have mentioned that the content is clipped with `transform`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I agree with @Dave Burton: using `transform-origin: 0 0;` does what I want. For example, to zoom the page to 150%: `transform: scale(1.5); transform-origin: 0 0;`. I believe @kumar_harsh 's otherwise good answer should be corrected.

Comment: @KaiCarver *if* you use this method, it'll always result in clipping. No matter which *point* you use for `transform-origin`. What I wrote is *just one example* of what value to use. You're of-course free to use `transform-origin: 0 0` if it suits your use-case (or if you don't care for what's there in the bottom-right corner)

Comment: @AngularM can you share a code snippet to show the behaviour? I'm sure there's some other reason for this.

Comment: Work fine but it adds horizontal scroll bar. how to avoid that?

Comment: add an `overflow:hidden` property to the body.

Comment: I'm trying to add this to the front page of my website. It definitely changes the size of the page, but it also makes everything originate to the left side of the screen. Is there a way to use this zoom whereby it just scales everything from a cernter point?

Comment: Nvm, all I had to do was take away the transform-origin line

Comment: I tried this in firefox 89.0.1 and it works. Support seems ok now.

Answer (score 24):

*If* your CSS is constructed completely around `ex` or `em` units, then this might be possible and feasible. You'd just need to declare `font-size: 150%` in your style for `body` or `html`. This should cause every other lengths to scale proportionally. You can't scale images this way, though, unless they get a style too.

But that's a very big *if* on most sites, anyway.

Comment: That would only change the size of my fonts. CTRL+ also proposition widens fixed widths, heights and image sizes as well.

Comment: I know, but it's as close as you can get with pure CSS. Also not only your fonts change but everything where the dimensions are specified as a multiple of the font's size. Meaning, everything where you used `%`, `em` or `ex` units.

Comment: That's just not correct. I've tested the solution I listed below (zoom + -moz-transform properties), and it works on FF3.5, IE6+, Safari, and Opera. It scales images as well as text. You can scale pages in CSS.

Answer (score 11):

**Scale is not the best option**

It will need some other adjustments, like margins paddings etc ..

**but the right option is**

```
zoom: 75%
```

Comment: ...not for Firefox which doesn't support it at all.

Comment: How about this one?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale

Comment: And how about this one? ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom
I have meant zoom is not quite right option, because it is not supported by Firefox, so you need to use both of those descriptors rather than to consider one of them to be better.

Comment: so what do you recommand as an alternative for that?

Comment: Do not search an alternative, use both of those descriptors.

Answer (score 9):

I have the following code that scales the entire page through CSS properties. The important thing is to set body.style.width to the inverse of the zoom to avoid horizontal scrolling. You must also set transform-origin to top left to keep the top left of the document at the top left of the window.

```
        var zoom = 1;
        var width = 100;

        function bigger() {
            zoom = zoom + 0.1;
            width = 100 / zoom;
            document.body.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
            document.body.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
            document.body.style.width = width + "%";
        }
        function smaller() {
            zoom = zoom - 0.1;
            width = 100 / zoom;
            document.body.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
            document.body.style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
            document.body.style.width = width + "%";
        }
```

Comment: Be careful doing this. You will sacrifice the ability to use  position: fixed

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot for Firefox in my case. I was scaling things to 0.7 (make everything smaller to fit more) but without the width adjustment, print version was cropped anyway.

Answer (score 7):

For Cross-Browser Compatibility :

Example Goes Below :

```
<html><body class="entire-webpage"></body></html>



.entire-webpage{
        zoom: 2;
        -moz-transform: scale(2);/* Firefox Property */
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(2);/* Opera Property */
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);/* Safari Property */
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
        transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

As Johannes says -- not enough rep to comment directly on his answer -- you can indeed do this as long as all elements' "dimensions are specified as a multiple of the font's size. Meaning, everything where you used %, em or ex units". Although I think % are based on containing element, not font-size.

And you wouldn't normally use these relative units for images, given they are composed of pixels, but there's a trick which makes this a lot more practical.

If you define `body{font-size: 62.5%};` then 1em will be equivalent to 10px. As far as I know this works across all main browsers.

Then you can specify your (e.g.) 100px square images with `width: 10em; height: 10em;` and assuming Firefox's scaling is set to default, the images will be their natural size.

Make `body{font-size: 125%};` and everything - including images - wil be double original size.

Comment: I don't understand, if I say body{font-size: 62.5%; font-size: 125%} - how would that define 1em to be 10px. Could the browser simply ignore the first font-size declaration and then simply make 125% = 10px?

Comment: I think you misunderstood.     you wouldn't do both at the same time.   62.5 x2 = 125...  to show how you can scale things by adjusting the value.

Comment: Yep. I should have said 'then if you use Javascript to set body {font-size: 125%} all page elements will double in size'.

Answer (score 3):

With this code 1em or 100% will equal to 1% of the body height

```
document.body.style.fontSize = ((window.innerHeight/100)*6.25)+"%"
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the zoom property in style.
Now interesting part is how to calculate it.
This is what I did.

```
let zoom = Number((window.innerWidth / window.screen.width).toFixed(3));
document.firstElementChild.style.zoom = zoom;
```

this will calculate the ratio of current window width to actual device width.
Then set that value to top level html element zoom property.
Top level html element can be accessed using `document.firstElementChild`

You can put this code inside `window.onresize` function to make the whole page zoom accordingly.

set the height of main wrapper div to 100% to prevent white space on zoom.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Tan has done this with his site - http://jontangerine.com/
Everything including images has been declared in ems. Everything. This is how the desired effect is achieved. Text zoom and screen zoom yield almost the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

CSS will not be able to zoom on demand, but if you couple CSS with JS, you could change some values to make a page look bigger.
However, as it has been said, this feature is standard nowadays in modern browsers: no need to replicate it. As a matter of fact, replicating it will slow down your website (more things to load, more JS or CSS to parse or execute and apply, etc.)

Comment: It is a standard browser feature, but adding the feature directly to the site means you don't have to rely on (1) user's expertise with their browser of choice and (2) browser-specific instructions

Answer (score 1):

```
 * {
transform: scale(1.1, 1.1)
}
```

this will transform every element on the page

Comment: Looks solved to me