# HTML Open a new window with zoom independent of parent window

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, window.open

In Firefox and Chrome, opening a new window via the JavaScript `window.open()` and zooming in/out in that window will cause the parent window it was opened from to zoom by the same amount.
Is there any way to stop this from happening, or a way to set the child window as its own parent so as to allow independent zooming?

Comment: In Firefox, the zoom seems to be linked to the domain you're on. So if I zoom this site, all the other stackoverflow tabs and windows zoom with it (but a tab on meta.stackoverflow.com does not). You could try opening the window on another sub-domain, but then you'll hit cross-site scripting limitations. You could implement this in JS, perhaps by adjusting the base font-size for the document in the popup window (assuming everything else is sized using `em` or other font-size relative units)?

Comment: I've tried to change the size...and it works for a second, but firefox then Resizes back to 100%.  humpWindow = window.open("HumpActivitySum.jsf", "_new", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=2000,height=1000,resizable=false", false);
   humpWindow.document.getElementById("all").style.fontSize="80%";

Comment: I suspect you'd need to wait for the document to load (e.g. use the `load` event or the jQuery `ready` event) before setting the font size, otherwise the CSS will load and set it back again!

Comment: I've tried to implement jQuery to achieve my results, but so far, the header just goes white whenever I hit a key.  I've tried this so when I hit enter, the page font size decreases, but no dice.

'<script language="JavaScript" src="resources/js/jquery-2.03.min.js">'
    $('all').on(keypress == '13', function(){
 var el = document.getElementById('all');
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
 var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
    
 el.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 5) + "px";});
</script>
<h:body id="all" >
.......
</h:body>'

Answer (score 0):

There's an article here on FF and Opera (?) That might be able to help -

[Firefox and Opera Zoom In Zoom Out using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962105/firefox-and-opera-zoom-in-zoom-out-using-javascript)

The article covers wanting to change the zoom through javascript.

You might be able to use this or something similar to zoom to what size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `zoom` css style at your new page.

```
.zoom {
  zoom: 150%;
}
```

This will give you independent zoom without affecting parent window.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/