# How can I zoom an HTML element in Firefox and Opera?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, zooming, opera

How can I zoom an HTML element in Firefox and Opera?

The `zoom` property is working in IE, Google Chrome and Safari, but it’s not working in Firefox and Opera.

Is there any method for adding this property to Firefox and Opera?

Comment: I'd refer you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/css-how-to-scale-entire-web-page-with-css) which answers yours pretty thoroughly.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this code, this’ll work:

```
-moz-transform: scale(2);
```

You can refer to [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/).

Comment: Ya this is working perfectly. Is there is any method to change -moz-transform scaling factor to percentage

Comment: It is a percentage in decimal form. (1 = 100% 2 = 200% 0.2 = 20%) But I believe you can use the percentage notation as well. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#percentages

Comment: The problem with this, is when you have fixed position elements. Zoom works in a different way than transform scale.

Comment: Also... what happens when ff supports zoom?  Will this double zoom? This doesn't seem like the solution imo.

Comment: this doesnt work with a sprite image though where we actually need to zoom in on a specific part of the image.

Comment: Meanwhile in 2010.

Answer (score 57):

Zoom and transform scale are not the same thing. They are applied at different times. Zoom is applied before the rendering happens, transform - after. The result of this is if you take a div with width/height = 100% nested inside of another div, with fixed size, if you apply zoom, everything inside your inner zoom will shrink, or grow, but if you apply transform your entire inner div will shrink (even though width/height is set to 100%, they are not going to be 100% after transformation).

Answer (score 41):

For me this works to counter the difference between zoom and scale transform, adjust for the intended origin desired:

```
zoom: 0.5;
-ms-zoom: 0.5;
-webkit-zoom: 0.5;
-moz-transform:  scale(0.5,0.5);
-moz-transform-origin: left center;
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `scale` instead! After many researches and tests I have made this plugin to achieve it cross browser:

```
$.fn.scale = function(x) {
    if(!$(this).filter(':visible').length && x!=1)return $(this);
    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('scaleContainer')){
        $(this).wrap($('<div class="scaleContainer">').css('position','relative'));
        $(this).data({
            'originalWidth':$(this).width(),
            'originalHeight':$(this).height()});
    }
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale('+x+')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale('+x+')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale('+x+')',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale('+x+')',
        'transform-origin': 'right bottom',
        '-ms-transform-origin': 'right bottom',
        '-moz-transform-origin': 'right bottom',
        '-webkit-transform-origin': 'right bottom',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': '0',
        'right': '0',
    });
    if(x==1)
        $(this).unwrap().css('position','static');else
            $(this).parent()
                .width($(this).data('originalWidth')*x)
                .height($(this).data('originalHeight')*x);
    return $(this);
};
```

usege:

```
$(selector).scale(0.5);
```

note:

It will create a wrapper with a class `scaleContainer`. Take care of that while styling content.

Comment: You can make this even more awesome by handling border width of the scaled element..
`.width($(this).data('originalWidth') * x + borderWidth)`

Answer (score 7):

I would change `zoom` for `transform` in all cases because, as explained by other answers, they are not equivalent. In my case it was also necessary to apply `transform-origin` property to place the items where I wanted.

This worked for me in Chome, Safari and Firefox:

```
transform: scale(0.4);
transform-origin: top left;
-moz-transform: scale(0.4);
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
```

Comment: transform and -moz-transform are mutually exclusive. transform and transform-origin worked for me.Thanks!

Comment: @JRichardsz Really? But Firefox supports transform. Why are both needed? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Comment: mozilla 2022 105.0 (64-bit) https://i.ibb.co/YWZdwXJ/mozilla-scale.png if you use one, the other is ignored or disabled

Answer (score 4):

```
zoom: 145%;
-moz-transform: scale(1.45);
```

use this to be on the safer side

Comment: This zooms 2x in webkit. Fist by zoom, second by scale

Answer (score 3):

I've been swearing at this for a while. Zoom is definitely not the solution, it works in chrome, it works partially in IE but moves the entire html div, firefox doesnt do a thing.

My solution that worked for me was using both a scaling and a translation, and also adding the original height and weight and then setting the height and weight of the div itself:

```
#miniPreview {
transform: translate(-710px, -1000px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(0.3, 0.3);
transform-origin: 1010px 1429px 0px;
width: 337px;
height: 476px;
```

Obviously change these to your own needs. It gave me the same result in all browsers.

Comment: This is the only correct answer! Scale alone leaves the original size of the element untouched.

Comment: This was the only answer that helped me solve my issue, which is that I wanted to scale elements up/down while maintaining the same width, so that more smaller elements would fit on the same row. All I had to do was scale the CSS width % as an inverse proportion to the CSS scale factor

Answer (score 2):

Only correct and W3C compatible answer is: `<html>` object and rem. transformation doesn't work correctly if you scale down (for example scale(0.5).

Use:

```
html
{
   font-size: 1mm; /* or your favorite unit */
}
```

and use in your code "rem" unit (including styles for `<body>`) instead metric units. "%"s without changes. For all backgrounds set background-size. Define font-size for body, that is inherited by other elements.

if any condition occurs that shall fire zoom other than 1.0 change the font-size for  tag (via CSS or JS).

for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320pt)
{
   html
   {
      font-size: 0.5mm; 
   }
}
```

This makes equivalent of zoom:0.5 without problems in JS with clientX and positioning during drag-drop events.

Don't use "rem" in media queries.

You really doesn't need zoom, but in some cases it can faster method for existing sites.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in uniform way in all browsers.
I went to to: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pulpitimage and added style for zoom and -moz-transform. I ran the same code on firefox, IE and chrome and got 3 different results.

```
<html>
<style>
body{zoom:3;-moz-transform: scale(3);}
</style>
<body>

<h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2>
<img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock"  />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to zoom the whole page in fireFox

```
-moz-transform: scale(2);
```

if I am using this code, the whole page scaled with y and x scroll not properly zoom

```
so Sorry to say fireFox not working well using "-moz-transform: scale(2);"
```

**

> Simply you can't zoom your page using css in fireFox

**

Answer (score 0):

does this work correctly for you? :

```
zoom: 145%;
-moz-transform: scale(1.45);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.45);
scale(1.45);
transform: scale(1.45);
```

Answer (score -1):

For me this works well with IE10, Chrome, Firefox and Safari:

```
   #MyDiv>*
   {
        zoom: 50%;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   }
```

This zooms all content in  to 50%.