# Python Selenium - zoom out by scrolling?

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, zooming

Is it possible to zoom out by scrolling using Selenium in Python? I don't want to zoom in and out using Ctrl +/- as that zooms in and out the entire page. I just need to zoom out part of the application and that is done by scrolling.

Comment: no matter how you zoom in/out, it's always on the entire webpage, do you mean zooming in/out in an `iframe`?

Comment: I suppose. Basically there is a header/search area at the top that would not be zoomed, only the content below.

Comment: could you post the link to this website

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. But it would be like the picture in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782465/zoom-specific-element-on-webcontent-html-css-javascript