# zoom css property is not working on firefox

Tags: html, css

I searched for this and found many solutions (using css3 transition).

Actually i am using `{zoom:1.5}` for all my buttons. But it is not working on firefox.
when I use transition property like:

```
-moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

All my buttons are overlapping. See ok and cancel button.
[image]

Is there any other alternative for this??
 any help??

Comment: `zoom` isn't part of the css spec and is not supported in Firefox http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Comment: thnx...I searched that already...isn't any alternative for this??

Comment: You can use `scale`, but not on each of the buttons separately. Use it on the whole popup.

Comment: I m using it on my all buttons that I have in my application not on each buttons separately.

Comment: @SumitRaghav use this property on the outer div which holding these buttons. then they will overlap on each other

Comment: You are using zoom (or scale) on all the buttons on your website? Why?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049342/how-can-i-zoom-a-div-in-firefox-and-opera

Answer (score 17):

To scale 50% and keep top center:

```
transform: scale(0.5);
transform-origin: 50% 0;
```

This did work with Safari/Firefox/Chrome (I did not test with IE)

Comment: for anyone using it: please keep in mind that this affects the width of the element.
Full-width elements will also scale, so if increasing the size, you will get a margin around your element.

Comment: It still takes up the same space. All the margins say 0. How do you fix this? @GlabbichRulz

Comment: unfortunately i did not yet find a proper zoom replacement for firefox

Answer (score 8):

You can use:-

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.8);
```

in firefox as alternative..

Comment: It still takes up the same space, unlike zoom.

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of the existing answers that did it for me:

```
-moz-transform: scale(...);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

With `50% 0` as ricardo's answer suggesst for the latter option there was a left margin.

Comment: It still takes up the same space, unlike zoom.

Answer (score 0):

What others have posted isn't feasible because the image will still take the same amount of space. Granted the image size doesn't need to resize programmatically, you can scale the image using Gimp, and remove zoom.

Image | Scale Image

[image: Scale Image]

File | Export As...

Answer (score -2):

put transform: scale(0.5);  instead of zoom:0.5px, this will work.
may be you have to change margins accordingly

Comment: How would you change the margins? Would effect how it looks in other browsers.