# Resizing a web page according to screen size using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a web application which uses classical ASP .NET MVC, but with bootstrap. The default page template I use looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Gymfed JuryTool</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/612fd28750.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>The Site</h3>
                <strong>JT</strong>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        Start
                    </a>
                </li>

                @{
                    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (userMenus != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var userMenu in userMenus)
                            {
                                //  Debug
                                Debug.WriteLine($"userMenu = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userMenu)}");
                                var controlName = userMenu.MenuName + "SubMenu";

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#@controlName" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                                        @userMenu.Caption
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="@controlName">
                                        @foreach (var menuItem in userMenu.MenuElements)
                                        {
                                            //  Debug
                                            Debug.WriteLine($"menuItem = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menuItem)}");

                                            <li>
                                                <a asp-area=@menuItem.AspArea asp-controller=@menuItem.AspController asp-action=@menuItem.AspAction>@menuItem.ElementName</a>
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
            <div class="container">
                &copy; 2021 - <i>Gymfed</i>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS files I include primarily are used for the collapsable menus and the likes.

Now the site looks fine, but to show everything on my screen I need to change the zoom to 80%.

I know Boostrap should be doing that for me, but though I follow their examples and everything looks fine when I zoom out to 80%...

I was wondering how I can have this happen automatically? Been looking around, but can't seem to find an actual answer to my question.

Comment: How do you zoom, do you zoom the entire webpage or zoom the content in the body? If it is based on body, you can refer to this post, which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344246/making-html-page-zoom-by-default

Comment: Wel, I want to show the entire page on the screen. To do this I currently use the zoom functionality of my browser. But how I  force the page to resize itself so it always shows itself completely on 1 scene?