# Zoom out to 90% in Firefox browser does not work using css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to zoom out my application through css by using

```
zoom: 90% !important
```

It works in IE, Chrome and Safari. But it is not working in Firefox. For Firefox im using :

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
```

But it does not seem to work. Can you please help me to achieve zoom out feature in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to have been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393588/complete-styles-for-cross-browser-css-zoom), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049342/how-can-i-zoom-an-html-element-in-firefox-and-opera).

The zoom property **is not supported in Firefox and Opera** : [see ref](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/#browser-support)

You can use `-moz-transform: scale(0.9)` but you will not get the same result:

```
body {
    zoom: 0.9;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. I tried it, but it doesn't change the size.  Only firefox does not respond to the style specifications. Other browsers it seems to work fine.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Have you tried opening the inspector in Moz and applying those properties to the body tag ?

Comment: Usefull links:
Css Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference
Can I use
http://caniuse.com/#

Comment: It does zoom out the body, but leaves space at the right and bottom as we have given  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;  When we manually click on - option and zoom out browser the UI look and feel we get, I'm not to achieve with -moz-transform:scale(0.9)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I will edit my answer