# How to zoom an input radio button element in a deprecated way that is supported by Opera version 11?

Tags: html, css, opera

I am developing a web application for a device which only supports Opera version 11. Because of this there are some CSS features that I cannot use.

Currently I am working on a form with input radio buttons which size I want to increase. The CSS method `zoom` (200%) does exactly what I want, but it is too new for the Opera browser. (https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom) Is there a deprecated way of accomplishing this?

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049342/how-can-i-zoom-an-html-element-in-firefox-and-opera) maybe can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add `border`, it will not work without it on Opera 11

```css
#rdBtn{
    border:0px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" id="rdBtn" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you also know why it does not work without this `border` style? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `font-size` with `@media`.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it helps to answer the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.