# Viewport meta tag for desktop browsers?

Tags: browser, viewport

My client is asking me to reduce size of current website for desktop browsers by 30%.

is there a css or meta tag to do it like viewport meta tag on a mobile browser?

Comment: You are looking for a `zoom` CSS property. Described here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1156526/368691.

Comment: You can enable the meta viewport tag (width) on desktop with this JS solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762579/get-meta-viewport-tag-to-work-on-desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the css `screen` [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

It is:

> Intended primarily for color computer screens.

You can use it this way:

```
@media screen {
  body { font-size: 70% }
}
```

There is also a `handheld` media type, primarily:

> Intended for handheld devices (typically small screen, limited bandwidth).

However, you will need to test the different devices and desktops your client is focusing on in order to determine how using these media types will effect the user experience.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Tried it on chrome, ie, and firefox. None of them worked. I put your css into my css file. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @Moon - I just put in a illustration of how to use it. You still need to add appropriate styles.

Answer (score 13):

Hmmm... I know this is an old question, but there is a MUCH better way to go about this: use the CSS `scale()` transform function on the `<html>` tag to scale EVERYTHING inside. Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mike_marcacci/6fMnH/

The magic is all here:

```
html {
    transform: scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    margin: -50% -50%;
}
```

Comment: This actually answers the question. The other answers primarily point out that this may not be the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: i really thought this was a nice solution, but it breaks so may things, unusefull in my case

Answer (score 3):

Odes is right.

```
@media screen {
  body { font-size: 70% }
}
```

But to make this really work well, you must use ems instead of px everywhere. That goes for margin and padding as well as width and height of all elements.

A good way to do this is to use SASS. Just create your own sass function to convert your px measurements into ems on the fly. Something like this will do:

```
@function em($px, $context: 16, $basesize: 16) {
  @return (($px/$basesize)/($context/16))+em;
}
```

Which then gets used in your CSS like so:

```
div { font-size:em(12); width: em(200,12); }
```

So, if the body font size was set to 100%, then the font size would be equivalent to 12px and the width of the div would be 200px wide.

Answer (score 3):

Here code for proportional scale and positioning, wnen using "transform: scale"

CSS

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
html
{
    position:absolute;
}
```

JS

```
var scale = 1;
$('html').css('transform','scale('+scale+')');

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
$('body').append(windowWidth);
$('body').append(' ' + windowWidth*scale );
//$('html').width(windowWidth*scale);


var width = (100*(1/scale));
var left = -(width*(1-scale))/2;

var height = (100*(1/scale));
var top = -(height*(1-scale))/2;

$('html').css('top', top+'%');
$('html').css('left', left+'%');
$('html').width(width+'%');
$('html').height(height+'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the meta viewport tag on desktop with JS. First you should derive the setting (width) from the meta tag:

```
var viewportcontent = $( "#myviewport" ).attr('content');
var viewportcontents = viewportcontent.split(",");
//if it starts with 'width='
for (var i = 0; i < viewportcontents.length; i++) {
  if(viewportcontents[i].lastIndexOf('width=', 0) === 0) {
    var wspec = viewportcontents[i].substring(6);
  }
}
```

Then you need a little JS and the solution of Mike to get this working solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqoeYJ. Note that this example forces the width to be 1200 pixels, but `initial-scale: 0.7` could be implemented in the same way.