# Scaling the viewport in non-mobile browsers

Tags: css, browser, width, viewport

One of my clients has requested that we add sidebars to a fixed-width site, which would make the overall width of the site too large for many smaller laptop displays. The ideal solution would be to use a responsive layout, which we'll probably end up doing sometime in the future, but for now we're looking for a quick fix. On mobile devices, the solution is dead simple because we can use viewport settings:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280">
```

Is there a way to force a non-mobile browser to scale in a similar fashion? I've tried meta tags and the CSS `zoom` property, but so far neither has worked on standard desktop browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787564/viewport-meta-tag-for-desktop-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the link above, you can use the CSS `scale()` transform function on the `<html>` or `<body>` tags to scale the entire page:

```
html {
  transform: scale(.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(.5);
  -o-transform: scale(.5);
}
```

You'll have to do some tricks to get the page to align correctly in the viewport, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries to resize your content (responsive layout) based on view width is not that hard to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Sample:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of media queries, and as I mentioned in my post, we'll probably end up building a fully responsive site *eventually*. For now, I think the CSS `scale()` solution mentioned in the post that AbdulS linked to is probably the right way to go as a quick fix.