# Thinking of the 'zoom' in responsive design

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, zooming

I am trying to do a responsive design with using HTML and CSS, here is my problem:

If you only resize the window, the layout fits and if you only zoom, layout fits again, I have no problem with it, but if you zoom when the window is resized, layout breaks a little.

Is it important to find a solution about this? I have no problem with 200%, 300% levels of zoom, mostly 400% or 500% make some problems to me.

Comment: Browser zoom is crap. Rounding errors on fractional pixels break layouts. It's a fact.

Comment: Perhaps this article about using EMs for media query breaks might be helpful? http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: This has to do exactly with the fact that @Jondlm said. In order to avoid the design break with zoom you need to use `em` unit of measurement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for article I am reading it.

Comment: Picking up on the other suggestions, http://susy.oddbird.net/ is one solid option if you to use em based media queries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, a responsive layout shouldn't need to be zoomed because it fits the device/browser window and has been designed to be "finger-friendly". To help with that, you can use this `viewport` to stop users from zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: This works on  my android browser thanks, but is there a way to do it on Chrome,Firefox or IE

Comment: Since those are desktop browsers, there isn't a "viewport" so to speak. You can check out the Media Types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787564/viewport-meta-tag-for-desktop-browsers

Comment: I know this is an old answer at this point, but this *completely* ignores issues like accessibility. People with impaired vision may **need** the zoom options.