# JavaScript/HTML/CSS: Zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Let's say I've got a page with a div, and a button. When you click the button, the div should be zoomed in on. In other words, if that div was 100px, when you zoom, it should then become, say, 200px. And all the children of this div should also be doubled in size.

What's the best way to do this?

My understanding is that there's a CSS `zoom`, but only in IE--it's not part of any CSS standard.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css , CSS `zoom` is supported by all major browsers except Firefox (Not sure about Firefox 4 though).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use CSS3's [`transform: scale()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Favaw/ - *(I used jQuery for convenience, but it's not a requirement)*

```
.zoomedIn2x {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);

    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

If you need to support older versions of IE than 9, then generate `.zoomedIn2x` using this tool:

- http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html

If you want to do this more dynamically (such as other levels of zoom), then instead use [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the jQuery plugin Zoomooz: http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: +1 for a cool plugin. Unfortunately when it comes to IE, it only works in version 9+ :(

Answer (score 1):

best solution is using
`zoom: 50%`

i made this example with javascript, you can test it and change it as you like

```js
var zoomediv = document.getElementById('zoomediv')

var zoomin_button = document.querySelector('#zoomin')
zoomin_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '125%'
})

var zoomout_button = document.querySelector('#zoomout')
zoomout_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '75%'
})
```

```css
div {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomediv">
  <h1>
    Title
  </h1>
  <p>
    this is a paragraph
  </p>
</div>

<button id="zoomin">
  <h1>
    +
  </h1>
</button>

<button id="zoomout">
  <h1>
    -
  </h1>
</button>
```