# Scaling Down Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a "post" creator that uses Bootstrap compatible `<div>, <span>`, etc tags. While the user types their post into a text box, I was hoping to create a "preview" next to it, at 1/2 page width size. So, everything inside it would be scaled down by 2.

My question: is there any way to scale down the Bootstrap elements so that it can be made into that preview? I can use `jquery` and such to take the input and format it dynamically onto the page, but I just need to know how to actually scale down everything.

Thanks!

Comment: If you put the contents in a container div with class row-fluid, then I think you can just use a div with class span12 and it will use 100% of the container width, so whatever the div width is set to, so will the contents.

Comment: what have you tried? The css docs for bootstrap are fairly straightforward.

Comment: Probably the cleanest/most magic way is with `transform:scale()`, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6130498/398242

Comment: sberry: That'd be very easy! I'll check it out and see if it works

Comment: charlietfl: I wasn't sure if I would have to dive into the bootstrap code, so I haven't tried much yet.
Wesley: That sounds very nice! I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you can make assumptions about the target audience or set minimum browser guidelines,  one option is to make use of [CSS3 2D Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp).  So, for example,  if you wanted your scale your preview window 50%, you could do something like:

```
#my-preview-div {
transform: scale(.5);
-ms-transform: scale(.5); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(.5); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(.5); /* Firefox */      
}
```

Then, you could use jquery to inject the preview html into your preview div, e.g.  `<div id="my-preview-div"></div>`.