# Built Responsive Full-Screen Website But Want Zoom Out Version of My Website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've built a responsive full-screen website. However, everything is way too big and I really like my website when I zoom out my website twice. Everything looks perfect!

I would like to know if there's a simpler way to achieve this other than just fixing and resizing everything. I literally need to dive in and fix every single thing if I want to get the look I want. However, my website looks perfect if I simple zoom out twice. I would like to confirm if there's a way that I don't know to achieve this.

Comment: what about forcing it manually? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18848058/1291428

Comment: Tried in out a different screen (different size/resolution)? You might use CSS tricks (transform for such tricks but it is a horrible idea. Fix the code.

Comment: @Sebas I've tried using JavaScript to force manually but it creates empty spaces across the website (all four sides).

Comment: You might get more useful advice if you posted a link to your site.