# Can we Zoom the browser window in python selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard

I am trying to ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT the Chrome( selenium webdriver) only using keyboard. I have tried --

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT).
```

but it is not working. Need answer in python.

Comment: What browser are you using? Show the complete code you have. Thanks.

Comment: Chk this answer. p://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content

Comment: @Vinoth the link you suggested does not have answer for python bindings. I need a solution in python

Comment: @alecxe I am using Chrome webdriver. I need to Zoom out the webdriver by sending keys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was just struggling with this.  I managed to find something that works for me, hopefully it works for you:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='zoom %'")
```

Have 'zoom%' = whatever zoom level you want.  (e.g. '67%')

Comment: For me it's not working with Selenium 2.53 and Firefox

Comment: @oxidworks did you try OP's syntax (which comes from [ActionChains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains))? That seems to work for webdrivers besides Chrome.

Comment: If your browser is already zoomed, the current zoom is threated as 100%. This doesn't equal to send  CONTROL + 0 to the browser to reset zoom.

Answer (score 18):

Environment:

- Selenium 3.6.0
- chromedriver 2.33
- Chrome version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I tried the ways (without use the CSS) that people suggested in other questions in the past. For example, the answers in this question: [Selenium webdriver zoom in/out page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content).

Or this: [Test zoom levels of page on browsers](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26533/test-zoom-levels-of-page-on-browsers)

without success.

So, I thought: if not with the shortcuts, what could be a different way to do that?

The idea is to use the "chrome://settings/" page in order to change the zoom:

[image]

Ok I know, for example from [Going through Chrome://settings by Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220400/going-through-chrome-settings-by-selenium), that every settings should be set in the [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html).

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336334/8845871) I noticed that in the [list of preferences](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc) the only paramater (I think) could be:

```
// Double that indicates the default zoom level.
const char kPartitionDefaultZoomLevel[] = "partition.default_zoom_level";
```

I tried, without success.

I want to repeat that I know it isn't the correct approach (and that will be different with different browser versions), but it works and, at least, was useful for me to understand how to go inside a shadow root element with selenium.

The following method return the elements inside a shadow root:

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root
```

It is useful because in the `chrome://settings/` page there are shadow root elements.

In order to do that in my browser, this is the path:

```
root1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//settings-ui")
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
container= shadow_root1.find_element_by_id("container")

root2= container.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-main")
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3=shadow_root2.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-basic-page")

shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)
basic_page = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id("basicPage")
```

[image]

```
settings_section= basic_page.find_element_by_xpath(".//settings-section[@section='appearance']")

root4= settings_section.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-appearance-page")
shadow_root4=expand_shadow_element(root4)
```

[image]

and finally:

```
settings_animated_pages= shadow_root4.find_element_by_id("pages")
neon_animatable=settings_animated_pages.find_element_by_css_selector("neon-animatable")

zoomLevel= neon_animatable.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@id='zoomLevel']/option[@value='0.5']")
zoomLevel.click()
```

[image]

The entire code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/pathTo/chromedriver')

def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root


driver.get('chrome://settings/')

root1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//settings-ui")
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
container= shadow_root1.find_element_by_id("container")

root2= container.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-main")
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3=shadow_root2.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-basic-page")

shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)
basic_page = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id("basicPage")

settings_section= basic_page.find_element_by_xpath(".//settings-section[@section='appearance']")

root4= settings_section.find_element_by_css_selector("settings-appearance-page")
shadow_root4=expand_shadow_element(root4)

settings_animated_pages= shadow_root4.find_element_by_id("pages")
neon_animatable=settings_animated_pages.find_element_by_css_selector("neon-animatable")

zoomLevel= neon_animatable.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@id='zoomLevel']/option[@value='0.5']")
zoomLevel.click()


driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
```

**EDIT**

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111539/can-we-zoom-the-browser-window-in-python-selenium-webdriver/47086145#comment81154391_47086145) by [@Florent B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florent-b) in the comments, we can obtain the same result simple with:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I got stuck at the beginning in `root1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//settings-ui")`. how did you define driver? I get a NoSuchElementException

Comment: @splinter what is the version of your chrome browser? as I said in the answer, I think depends on this. If you inspect the html in your "chrome://settings/", is the same of mine? Anyway, at the end of the answer there is the entire code.

Comment: Instead of updating the DOM, you could simply call the API in the page: `driver.get("chrome://settings/")` then `driver.execute_script("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);")`.

Comment: @FlorentB. Thanks, Is there a typing mistake in your call? because I obtain this exception: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @Davide Patti, it works just fine with my config (win10 chromium 62.0.3202.62). You can check the source [here](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=onZoomLevelChange_&type=cs). It could be a sync issue. Try with a timeout: `driver.execute_script("setTimeout(function(){chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom‌​(1.5);}, 5);")`

Comment: @FlorentB. I got it the problem. If I copy and paste your example in the console of Chrome, I see  2 dots after "Zoom". Something like this: driver.execute_script("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom‌..​(1.5);"). In my ide (intelliJ) this dots weren't showed. That's why my error. If I remove this dots, works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @FlorentB., you should post this as a solution rather than just in the comments. This is the only solution in which the zoom persists across page loads, and that's an incredibly useful behavior.

Answer (score 13):

firefox solution for me,

[Zoom body browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847432/zoom-body-browser)

zoom is a non-standard property, use transform instead (demo):

`driver.execute_script("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.8)'")`

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4244

`driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.50)";')`

`driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "0 0";')`

Comment: The OP asked specifically about Chrome, not FireFox. Stack Overflow is a Q & A site, the answer box is only for complete answers to the question that was asked. You should put a bit more effort in. Test this solution in Chrome and indicate it works in the answer. Otherwise this should be made into a comment (which you will be able to do once you have earned enough reputation), as it is relevant but does not directly answer the question.

Comment: I found this solution useful and have not found a similar question asked for Firefox on SO, so happy this is here.

Comment: Same as the zoom property. If your browser is already zoomed, the current zoom is threated as 100%. This doesn't equal to send CONTROL + 0 to the browser to reset zoom.

Comment: document.body.style.transform works on Chrome as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can invoke the Chrome driver to zoom without having to use CSS. There are methods packaged into the Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer, one being `Input.synthesizePinchGesture` aka zoom in/out.

**For ease of use**, with regards to the DevTools Protocol API, we will use a class called `MyChromeDriver` with `webdriver.Chrome` as a metaclass and a new method for sending these commands to Chrome:

```
# selenium
from selenium import webdriver
# json
import json

class MyChromeDriver(webdriver.Chrome):
    def send_cmd(self, cmd, params):
        resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command_and_get_result" % self.session_id
        url = self.command_executor._url + resource
        body = json.dumps({'cmd':cmd, 'params': params})
        response = self.command_executor._request('POST', url, body)
        return response.get('value')
```

**1. Setup our webdriver** and `get` some page:

```
webdriver = MyChromeDriver()
webdriver.get("https://google.com")
```

**2. Send Chrome the `Input.synthesizePinchGesture` command** along with its [parameters](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#method-synthesizePinchGesture) via our new method `send_cmd`:

```
webdriver.send_cmd('Input.synthesizePinchGesture', {
                        'x': 0,
                        'y': 0,
                        'scaleFactor': 2,
                        'relativeSpeed': 800, # optional
                        'gestureSourceType': 'default' # optional
                    })
```

**3. Walla! Chrome's zoom is invoked:**
[image]

As a side note, there are tons of other commands you could use with `send_cmd`. Find them here:  https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Based off this answer: [Take full page screen shot in Chrome with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199076/take-full-page-screen-shot-in-chrome-with-selenium/45201692#45201692)

Comment: hi, Cole, i tried your code, it returns ```AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'send_cmd'```, do you have any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned that `Need it to work in Chrome. The current solutions are only for Firefox`, here are a few updates and options :

1. **Zoom the CSS :**

   ```
   driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
   ```

   This option did work for me. But it zooms the CSS, not the Chrome Browser. So probably you are not looking at that.
2. **Zoom In & Zoom Out the Chrome Browser :**

After [**`4131`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4131), [**`4133`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4133) and [**`1621`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1621) the **`fullscreen()`** mode got supported to `Zoom In` through **Selenium-Java Clients** but it's not yet publicly released to **PyPI**.

> **I can see it's implemented but not pushed. `Selenium 3.7 (Python)` will be out soon. The push to sync version numbers will include that.**

3. **Configure the `webdriver` to open the Browser :**

If your requirement is to execute the `Test Suite` in `Full Screen` mode, you can always use the **`Options`** Class and configure the webdriver instance with **`--kiosk`** argument as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
# zoom in firefox browser
driver.get("about:preferences")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "// [@id='defaultZoom']"))
ActionChains(driver).click(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@value='50']")).perform()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).