# Where can I find a list of all available ChromeOption arguments?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I am a big advocate for reading the manual. But in this case, despite searching online for some time I cannot find a manual explaining all of the available `ChromeOptions` arguments. Somewhere there must be a listing of all of the string arguments and what they mean.

For example, here are some that I found by stumbling through examples:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("incognito");
options.AddArguments("test-type");
```

Can someone please direct me to a listing? I am using C# 4.6, Selenium 2.45.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

List of common switches :
[/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)

List of headless switches :
[/master/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc)

To search other switches :
https://source.chromium.org/search?q=file:switches.cc&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

List of preferences:
[/master/chrome/common/pref_names.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/chrome/common/pref_names.h)

Answer (score 109):

This is the one I use:
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
```

and so forth :)

Comment: This is a great resource, but Florent's answer is from the official source. Thank you

Comment: Actually not all switches that appear in this non-official resource are listed in the official website. For example there is no mentioning of `--headless` switch in the official list.

Comment: +1 This list has significantly more options, more details, and is much easier to read. Even the chrome man page says not all options are listed/official so a resource like this is much more useful. The list also auto updates.

Comment: Is there a similar list for the Firefox and Internet Explorer drivers? I'm having no luck digging those up.

Comment: This should've been included in official docs. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, this led me to try --start-minimized using Edge Chromium 105 which works, finally I can launch a window that is at least somewhat hidden. Now how to close it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer about how to use the ChromeOptions used:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
```

Comment: why some arguments are with -- (2 dashes) at the beginning but some without?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be like this:

1. Try to eliminate the "--"
2. options > option
3. Capitalize "A" in "Add"
4. Arguments > Argument

```
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.AddArgument("test-type");
    option.AddArgument("start-maximized");
    option.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");
    option.AddArgument("enable-precise-memory-info");
    option.AddArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
    option.AddArgument("disable-default-apps");
    option.AddArgument("test-type=browser");
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest documentation for Selenium 4 mention ChromOptions arguments in 'Arguments' section -

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/#arguments