# Where can I find a list of all available ChromeOptions with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

Where can I find a list of all available Chrome Options with selenium?

While crawling with selenium in a python environment, I had to use flash in the chrome webdriver.
so I tried to find a setting that would allow Flash and I found these answers.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test

[Selenium.Chrome where can I find a list of all available ChromeOption arguments? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335671/selenium-chrome-where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-available-chromeoption-arguments)

but I really want to find official document
about these arguments :

- **profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins**
- **profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player**

I think that exist because some people said like above two answers.
but I can't found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. open `chrome://version` in chrome address bar
2. open the folder of **Profile Path:**, there will be a file `perference`
   [image]
3. copy and open the `perference` file, it's a JSON file, you can use JSON formater or J[SON viewer online](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). 
   **important**, please open the copied one to avoid break your chrome if you did changes.
4. I think the configuration related to flash under `profile.content_settings`
5. open `chrome://settings/content/flash` in chrome address bar, do waht you wanted settings for flash, your changes will be updated into `perference` file,
6. Find out the difference between the updated and copied `perference` file. 
   The difference should be you wanted chrome perference.
7. set perference when build ChromeOptions, like `profile.content_settings.xxx=xxx`
   [image]

Alternative, you can pre-config the flash settings(`chrome://settings/content/flash`) in current user profile and use user profile to build ChromeOptions.
[image]

Some reference:

- [Manage Flash in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7084871?hl=en)
- [Default user preferences](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en)
- [Preferences vs. Policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences)
- [Policy List](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3)
- [Policy List - DefaultPluginsSetting](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultPluginsSetting)

Policy more close to using registry/system level setting to effect all users in one machine; Preference work under user profile only effect one user, user can use it to customize upon Policy settings. But Policy has higher priority than Preference.

Comment: I guess I'll have to learn about chrome profile but this answer quite helped to me. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the links of the most widely used *ChromeDriver* properties and *ChromeOptions*:

- ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome: [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)
- Peter Beverloo: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
- Chromium Project: [Chrome Preferences](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc)
- Chromium Project: [Chrome Switches](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)