# How do I set Chrome upload directory with Selenium & VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome

How do i set default upload path with selinium and chrome. eg going to a webpage, and upload. this opens a fileexploere, but it always opens c:\users[me]
I want to be able to set anoter default path.

i have seen this to set download path
driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\temp"
and i tried to alter it
driver.SetPreference "upload.default_directory", "c:\temp"
but it dosnt work.

Chrome Version 102.0.5005.115 - win10

Answer (score 0):

Found it

from this helpfull link
[Where can I find a list of all available ChromeOption arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335671/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-available-chromeoption-arguments)

theres a link to "List of preferences:"

in here i found
selectfile.last_directory
So i set
`driver.SetPreference "selectfile.last_directory", "c:\temp`" or what you want