# Take full page screenshot in Chrome with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know this was not possible [before](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294), but now with the following update:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots

this seems to be possible using Chrome Dev Tools.

Is it possible now using Selenium in Java?

Comment: AFAIK this is possible in `selenium`+`PhantomJS`

Comment: Yes but I need Chrome Driver

Comment: If you're using Java, it looks like someone has created a nice library to do this sort of thing for you. Maybe give this a try https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot/

Comment: @stewartm that library plays with javascript to scroll through the page and take many screenshots.. I have a similar approach in my code but that does not work well when there's a floating window..

Comment: regarding ashot -- it scrolls, so floating headers are repeated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this with Selenium Webdriver in Java takes a bit of work.. As hinted by Florent B. we need to change some classes uses by the default ChromeDriver to make this work. First we need to make a new DriverCommandExecutor which adds the new Chrome commands:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandInfo;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService;

public class MyChromeDriverCommandExecutor extends DriverCommandExecutor {
    private static final ImmutableMap<String, CommandInfo> CHROME_COMMAND_NAME_TO_URL;

    public MyChromeDriverCommandExecutor(DriverService service) {
        super(service, CHROME_COMMAND_NAME_TO_URL);
    }

    static {
        CHROME_COMMAND_NAME_TO_URL = ImmutableMap.of("launchApp", new CommandInfo("/session/:sessionId/chromium/launch_app", HttpMethod.POST)
        , "sendCommandWithResult", new CommandInfo("/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result", HttpMethod.POST)
        );
    }
}
```

After that we need to create a new ChromeDriver class which will then use this thing. We need to create the class because the original has no constructor that lets us replace the command executor... So the new class becomes:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocalStorage;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.Location;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocationContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.SessionStorage;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.TouchScreen;
import org.openqa.selenium.mobile.NetworkConnection;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.FileDetector;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteTouchScreen;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5.RemoteLocationContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5.RemoteWebStorage;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.mobile.RemoteNetworkConnection;

public class MyChromeDriver  extends RemoteWebDriver implements LocationContext, WebStorage, HasTouchScreen, NetworkConnection {
    private RemoteLocationContext locationContext;
    private RemoteWebStorage webStorage;
    private TouchScreen touchScreen;
    private RemoteNetworkConnection networkConnection;

    //public MyChromeDriver() {
    //  this(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), new ChromeOptions());
    //}
    //
    //public MyChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service) {
    //  this(service, new ChromeOptions());
    //}

    public MyChromeDriver(Capabilities capabilities) {
        this(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), capabilities);
    }

    //public MyChromeDriver(ChromeOptions options) {
    //  this(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), options);
    //}

    public MyChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service, Capabilities capabilities) {
        super(new MyChromeDriverCommandExecutor(service), capabilities);
        this.locationContext = new RemoteLocationContext(this.getExecuteMethod());
        this.webStorage = new RemoteWebStorage(this.getExecuteMethod());
        this.touchScreen = new RemoteTouchScreen(this.getExecuteMethod());
        this.networkConnection = new RemoteNetworkConnection(this.getExecuteMethod());
    }

    @Override
    public void setFileDetector(FileDetector detector) {
        throw new WebDriverException("Setting the file detector only works on remote webdriver instances obtained via RemoteWebDriver");
    }

    @Override
    public LocalStorage getLocalStorage() {
        return this.webStorage.getLocalStorage();
    }

    @Override
    public SessionStorage getSessionStorage() {
        return this.webStorage.getSessionStorage();
    }

    @Override
    public Location location() {
        return this.locationContext.location();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.locationContext.setLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public TouchScreen getTouch() {
        return this.touchScreen;
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionType getNetworkConnection() {
        return this.networkConnection.getNetworkConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionType setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType type) {
        return this.networkConnection.setNetworkConnection(type);
    }

    public void launchApp(String id) {
        this.execute("launchApp", ImmutableMap.of("id", id));
    }
}
```

This is mostly a copy of the original class, but with some constructors disabled (because some of the needed code is package private). If you are in need of these constructors you must place the classes in the package org.openqa.selenium.chrome.

With these changes you are able to call the required code, as shown by Florent B., but now in Java with the Selenium API:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Command;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ChromeExtender {
    @Nonnull
    private MyChromeDriver m_wd;

    public ChromeExtender(@Nonnull MyChromeDriver wd) {
        m_wd = wd;
    }

    public void takeScreenshot(@Nonnull File output) throws Exception {
        Object visibleSize = evaluate("({x:0,y:0,width:window.innerWidth,height:window.innerHeight})");
        Long visibleW = jsonValue(visibleSize, "result.value.width", Long.class);
        Long visibleH = jsonValue(visibleSize, "result.value.height", Long.class);

        Object contentSize = send("Page.getLayoutMetrics", new HashMap<>());
        Long cw = jsonValue(contentSize, "contentSize.width", Long.class);
        Long ch = jsonValue(contentSize, "contentSize.height", Long.class);

        /*
         * In chrome 61, delivered one day after I wrote this comment, the method forceViewport was removed.
         * I commented it out here with the if(false), and hopefully wrote a working alternative in the else 8-/
         */
        if(false) {
            send("Emulation.setVisibleSize", ImmutableMap.of("width", cw, "height", ch));
            send("Emulation.forceViewport", ImmutableMap.of("x", Long.valueOf(0), "y", Long.valueOf(0), "scale", Long.valueOf(1)));
        } else {
            send("Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride",
                ImmutableMap.of("width", cw, "height", ch, "deviceScaleFactor", Long.valueOf(1), "mobile", Boolean.FALSE, "fitWindow", Boolean.FALSE)
            );
            send("Emulation.setVisibleSize", ImmutableMap.of("width", cw, "height", ch));
        }

        Object value = send("Page.captureScreenshot", ImmutableMap.of("format", "png", "fromSurface", Boolean.TRUE));

        // Since chrome 61 this call has disappeared too; it does not seem to be necessary anymore with the new code.
        // send("Emulation.resetViewport", ImmutableMap.of()); 
        send("Emulation.setVisibleSize", ImmutableMap.of("x", Long.valueOf(0), "y", Long.valueOf(0), "width", visibleW, "height", visibleH));

        String image = jsonValue(value, "data", String.class);
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(image);

        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output)) {
            fos.write(bytes);
        }
    }

    @Nonnull
    private Object evaluate(@Nonnull String script) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("returnByValue", Boolean.TRUE);
        param.put("expression", script);

        return send("Runtime.evaluate", param);
    }

    @Nonnull
    private Object send(@Nonnull String cmd, @Nonnull Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> exe = ImmutableMap.of("cmd", cmd, "params", params);
        Command xc = new Command(m_wd.getSessionId(), "sendCommandWithResult", exe);
        Response response = m_wd.getCommandExecutor().execute(xc);

        Object value = response.getValue();
        if(response.getStatus() == null || response.getStatus().intValue() != 0) {
            //System.out.println("resp: " + response);
            throw new MyChromeDriverException("Command '" + cmd + "' failed: " + value);
        }
        if(null == value)
            throw new MyChromeDriverException("Null response value to command '" + cmd + "'");
        //System.out.println("resp: " + value);
        return value;
    }

    @Nullable
    static private <T> T jsonValue(@Nonnull Object map, @Nonnull String path, @Nonnull Class<T> type) {
        String[] segs = path.split("\\.");
        Object current = map;
        for(String name: segs) {
            Map<String, Object> cm = (Map<String, Object>) current;
            Object o = cm.get(name);
            if(null == o)
                return null;
            current = o;
        }
        return (T) current;
    }
}
```

This lets you use the commands as specified, and creates a file with a png format image inside it. You can of course also directly create a BufferedImage by using ImageIO.read() on the bytes.

Comment: Great work!!! Any chance you could add the imports for the ChromeExtender class? I took a guess at a few of them.

Comment: Hi @SiKing, I added the imports. But take care, Chrome 61, which I got today, removes the forceViewport call used in my original example. I have added an alternative which seems to work for me in the code for takeScreenshot().

Comment: Emulation.resetViewport" does not seem to work on chrome 61 (was OK on chrome 60). Is there an alternative?

Comment: It seems like that call is not needed anymore. I just removed it, and that seems to do OK?

Comment: it turned out using only Emulation.setVisibleSize before the screenshot and resetting it to previous value after does the trick. At least in chrome 61. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 38):

Yes it possible to take a full page screenshot with Selenium since Chrome v59. The Chrome driver has two new endpoints to directly call the DevTools API:

```
/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result
/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command
```

The Selenium API doesn't implement these commands, so you'll have to send them directly with the underlying executor. It's not straightforward, but at least it's possible to produce the exact same result as DevTools.

Here's an example with python working on a local or remote instance:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import json, base64

capabilities = {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions':  {
    'useAutomationExtension': False,
    'args': ['--disable-infobars']
  }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")

png = chrome_takeFullScreenshot(driver)

with open(r"C:\downloads\screenshot.png", 'wb') as f:
  f.write(png)
```

, and the code to take a full page screenshot :

```py
def chrome_takeFullScreenshot(driver) :

  def send(cmd, params):
    resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command_and_get_result" % driver.session_id
    url = driver.command_executor._url + resource
    body = json.dumps({'cmd':cmd, 'params': params})
    response = driver.command_executor._request('POST', url, body)
    return response.get('value')

  def evaluate(script):
    response = send('Runtime.evaluate', {'returnByValue': True, 'expression': script})
    return response['result']['value']

  metrics = evaluate( \
    "({" + \
      "width: Math.max(window.innerWidth, document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth)|0," + \
      "height: Math.max(innerHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)|0," + \
      "deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio || 1," + \
      "mobile: typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined'" + \
    "})")
  send('Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride', metrics)
  screenshot = send('Page.captureScreenshot', {'format': 'png', 'fromSurface': True})
  send('Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride', {})

  return base64.b64decode(screenshot['data'])
```

With Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

    ChromeDriverEx driver = new ChromeDriverEx(options);

    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions");
    File file = driver.getFullScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
}
```

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandInfo;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpMethod;


public class ChromeDriverEx extends ChromeDriver {

    public ChromeDriverEx() throws Exception {
        this(new ChromeOptions());
    }

    public ChromeDriverEx(ChromeOptions options) throws Exception {
        this(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), options);
    }

    public ChromeDriverEx(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options) throws Exception {
        super(service, options);
        CommandInfo cmd = new CommandInfo("/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result", HttpMethod.POST);
        Method defineCommand = HttpCommandExecutor.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineCommand", String.class, CommandInfo.class);
        defineCommand.setAccessible(true);
        defineCommand.invoke(super.getCommandExecutor(), "sendCommand", cmd);
    }

    public <X> X getFullScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> outputType) throws Exception {
        Object metrics = sendEvaluate(
            "({" +
            "width: Math.max(window.innerWidth,document.body.scrollWidth,document.documentElement.scrollWidth)|0," +
            "height: Math.max(window.innerHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.scrollHeight)|0," +
            "deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio || 1," +
            "mobile: typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined'" +
            "})");
        sendCommand("Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride", metrics);
        Object result = sendCommand("Page.captureScreenshot", ImmutableMap.of("format", "png", "fromSurface", true));
        sendCommand("Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride", ImmutableMap.of());
        String base64EncodedPng = (String)((Map<String, ?>)result).get("data");
        return outputType.convertFromBase64Png(base64EncodedPng);
    }

    protected Object sendCommand(String cmd, Object params) {
        return execute("sendCommand", ImmutableMap.of("cmd", cmd, "params", params)).getValue();
    }

    protected Object sendEvaluate(String script) {
        Object response = sendCommand("Runtime.evaluate", ImmutableMap.of("returnByValue", true, "expression", script));
        Object result = ((Map<String, ?>)response).get("result");
        return ((Map<String, ?>)result).get("value");
    }
}
```

Comment: any hint on how to do that in java?

Comment: Try to extend the `HttpCommandExecutor` and call `defineCommand` to use the new endpoint. Then instantiate a new
RemoteWebDriver with the extended `HttpCommandExecutor`.

Comment: "Emulation.resetViewport" does not seem to work on chrome 61 (was OK on chrome 60). Is there an alternative?

Comment: The commands "Emulation.forceViewport" and "Emulation.resetViewport" are no longer present in the API and `Emulation.setVisibleSize` is now deprecated. There were replaced by "Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride" and "Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride". It seems no longer possible to freeze the size of the viewport. So the screenshot will probably be truncated at the bottom if the size of the content is set according to the size of the viewport. I also added the code for Java.

Comment: it turned out using only Emulation.setVisibleSize before the screenshot and resetting it to previous value after does the trick. At least in chrome 61. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Majid Laissi, `Emulation.setVisibleSize` is tagged as deprecated and will be removed from the API.

Comment: I know I'm not allowed to comment to say thanks, but dammit I can't find another way to thank you. Well done on this answer, hope you can read it before it gets removed

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4, `FirefoxDriver` provides a `getFullPageScreenshotAs` method that handles vertical and horizontal scrolling, as well as fixed elements (e.g. navbars). `ChromeDriver` may implement this method in later releases.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver");
final FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
// set options...
final FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
File fullScreenshotFile = driver.getFullPageScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// File will be deleted once the JVM exits, so you should copy it
```

For `ChromeDriver`, the [selenium-shutterbug](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug) library can be used.

```
Shutterbug.shootPage(driver, Capture.FULL, true).save();
// Take screenshot of the whole page using Chrome DevTools
```