# Selenium + Firefox: transparent element screenshots

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm taking screenshots of elements in Selenium using the Firefox driver's `element.screenshot_as_png`. The resulting images include other elements that are underneath, as well as a white background behind everything (even though the page has no background colour set).

I just want the element alone on a transparent background, *nothing else*. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656622/transparent-screenshot-with-headless-chromedriver-via-selenium) there's a way to do it in Chrome. Any chance to get the same thing with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Take Screenshot Like That!

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

You Can Also Use `Pillow`!

```
import pyscreenshot
im = pyscreenshot.grab()
im.save('ss.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to screenshot a specific **element**, not the entire window. Also those methods don't handle overlapping elements and transparency.