# How to block request using selenium remote webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a program currently working properly and blocking requests with selenium chrome driver with these lines of code:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": urls})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
```

But when I run the same code with selenium remote web driver I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'execute_cdp_cmd'
```

Found this solution to run the execute_cdp_cmd command
[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297877/to-set-mutationobserver-how-to-inject-javascript-before-page-loading-using-sele/47298910#47298910) and implemented it in this way but nothing really happens so my question is. Is there any way to block requests in the selenium remote driver?

```
def send(driver, cmd, params={}):
    resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command_and_get_result" % driver.session_id
    url = driver.command_executor._url + resource
    body = json.dumps({'cmd': cmd, 'params': params})
    response = driver.command_executor._request('POST', url, body)
    if response['status']:
        raise Exception(response.get('value'))
    return response.get('value')


def add_script(driver):
    # Read blocked URL's
    with open("blockedURLs.txt") as file:
        urls = file.readlines()
        urls = [line.rstrip() for line in urls]

    send(driver, 'Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": urls})
    send('Network.enable', {})

WebDriver.add_script = add_script
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', options=chrome_options)
```