# Selenium. Bring-up window on the front

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If you run the following code, then at each iteration of the cycle, the browser will bring up on the front and get focus.

```
public class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://i.imgur.com/cdA7SBB.jpg");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      var ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
      ss.SaveAsFile("D:/imgs/i.jpg");
    }
  }
}
```

The question is: why does this happen and can it be turned off? headless mod does not fit.

It seems that this always happens when Selenium needs to save / read the file or start the process.

Comment: `Selenium` needs focus to interact with the DOM elements. What exactly do you want to `turn off`?

Comment: @DebanjanB, roughly speaking, I want the browser does not interfere with me and also i don't want use headless mode.

Comment: Trying to understand your usecase, if not the `WebPage` or any `WebElement`, for which object are you trying to get the `Screenshot` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To take a screenshot, chromedriver activates the window. It's by design and there's no option to avoid it even though it's technically possible. 
For the relevant sources have a look at [window_commands.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/window_commands.cc?l=1289).

You could however avoid the effect by moving the window off-screen:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(-32000, -32000);
```

or by launching the browser off-screen:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--window-position=-32000,-32000");
```

UPDATE

You can avoid the activation by taking the screenshot directly via the devtool API. Here's a class to override `GetScreenshot`:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using JObject = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;


class ChromeDriverEx : ChromeDriver
{
    public ChromeDriverEx(ChromeOptions options = null) 
        : base(options ?? new ChromeOptions()) {
        var repo = base.CommandExecutor.CommandInfoRepository;
        repo.TryAddCommand("send", new CommandInfo("POST", "/session/{sessionId}/chromium/send_command_and_get_result"));
    }

    public new Screenshot GetScreenshot() {
        object response = Send("Page.captureScreenshot", new JObject {{"format", "png"}, {"fromSurface", true}});
        string base64 = (string)((JObject)response)["data"];
        return new Screenshot(base64);
    }

    protected object Send(string cmd, JObject args) {
        return this.Execute("send",  new JObject {{"cmd", cmd}, {"params", args}}).Value;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriverEx();
driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("/tmp/screenshot.png");
driver.Quit();
```

Comment: Thx for answer. This solution hides the obsessive browser window, but does not solve the problem of the browser's stealing of focus.

Comment: You won't be able to deactivate to focus out of the box since the driver doesn't provide the option. You have two options. Either rebuild chromedriver with a modified `window_commands.cc.` or extend `ChromeDriver` to directly take a screenshot via the devtools protocol. You'll find an example with Java/Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199076/take-full-page-screen-shot-in-chrome-with-selenium/45201692#45201692).

Comment: do you know why chromedriver developers made "grip focus" solution by design, now i can't understand why chrome driver need focus for take screenshot?

Comment: The page could change its content when the focus is lost. Keep in mind that Selenium was mainly designed for testing. So taking a screenshot of a non activated window doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Brilliant answer, this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: @FlorentB. can you please update the code for Selenium 4?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke **`Navigate().GoToUrl("url")`** method through your `Automation` script, it is expected that your script will be interacting with some of the elements on the webpage. So for **`Selenium`** to interact with those elements, `Selenium` needs **focus**. Hence **opening up the browser**, **bring up on the front** and **getting the focus** is the default phenomenon implemented through `Navigate().GoToUrl("url")`.

Now **`Default Mode`** or **`Headless Mode`** is controlled by the **`ChromeOption`**/**`FirefoxOptions`** class which is passed as an argument while initializing the `WebDriver` instance and will call `Navigate().GoToUrl("url")`. So, `Navigate().GoToUrl("url")` would have no impact how the `WebDriver` instance is controlling the `Mode of Operation` i.e. `Default Mode` or `Headless Mode`.

Now when you try to invoke the method from [**`ITakesScreenshot Interface`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_ITakesScreenshot.htm) i.e. [**`ITakesScreenshot.GetScreenshot Method`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ITakesScreenshot_GetScreenshot.htm) which is defined as :

```
Gets a Screenshot object representing the image of the page on the screen.
```

In case of `WebDriver` instance which extends **`ITakesScreenshot`**, makes the best effort depending on the browser to return the following in order of preference:

1. **`Entire page`**
2. **`Current window`**
3. **`Visible portion of the current frame`**
4. **`The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser`**

There may be some instances when the browser looses the focus. In that case you can use `IJavascriptExecutor` to regain the focus as follows :

```
((IJavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with an issue when generic GetScreenshot() in parallel testing was causing browser to lose focus. Some elements were being removed from DOM and my tests were failing. I've come up with a working solution for **Edge and Chrome 100+** with **Selenium 4.1**:

```
public Screenshot GetScreenshot()
    {
        IHasCommandExecutor executor = webDriverInstance as IHasCommandExecutor;
        var sessionId = ((WebDriver)webDriverInstance).SessionId;
        var command = new HttpCommandInfo(HttpCommandInfo.PostCommand, $"/session/{sessionId}/chromium/send_command_and_get_result");
        executor.CommandExecutor.TryAddCommand("Send", command);

        var response = Send(executor, "Page.captureScreenshot", new JObject { { "format", "png" }, { "fromSurface", true } });
        var base64 = ((Dictionary<string, object>)response.Value)["data"];
        return new Screenshot(base64.ToString());
    }

    private Response Send(IHasCommandExecutor executor, string cmd, JObject args)
    {         
        var json = new JObject { { "cmd", cmd }, { "params", args } }; 
        var command = new Command("Send", json.ToString());
        return executor.CommandExecutor.Execute(command);
    }
```