# How to take a screenshot of a full browser page and its elements using selenium-webdriver/capybara in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, screenshot

I am working on screenshot automation. In particular, I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Prompt the user for the links to different pages on the website X
2. Prompt the user for the class name Y
3. I should be able to visit a website X login page, provide login details (assume they are known), click on "submit" button, that should redirect me to the "home" page
4. Then I look at the list of links, provided by the user, visit each page and take screenshots of all elements, that have class Y (or the entire page)
5. Save them in the current directory

[Please click on the link for visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLE40.png)

**I wanted to implement the following solution in Ruby (but I am also open to any other suggestions):**

1) Take a screenshot of the entire scrollable page on the website X 2) Find the element(s) of class Y, in particular its location on the page, width and height. 3) Crop the full screenshot so that only desired element is visible

**Problem is the following:**

I cannot take a screenshot of the entire page, I was only able to take a screenshot of the visible area of my screen.

**This is what I tried and corresponding problems:**

**SOLUTION 1 (Ruby - General):**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox #:chrome

driver.navigate.to "https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X"
driver.manage.window.maximize # <- works for firefox only
driver.save_screenshot('picture1.png')

# Problem: it captures only the viewable area, 
# not an entire page
```

**SOLUTION 2 (Ruby - Window Resizing):**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox #:chrome
driver.navigate.to 'https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X'

width  = driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,document.body.offsetWidth,document.documentElement.clientWidth,document.documentElement.scrollWidth,document.documentElement.offsetWidth);")
height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,document.body.offsetHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight,document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.offsetHeight);")

driver.manage.window.resize_to(width, height) # <- resizes the window
driver.manage.window.full_screen  # <- works, but in chrome throws:
                                  # full_screen': undefined method `full_screen_window'

picture = driver.screenshot_as(:png)

File.open('picture2.png', 'w+') do |fh|
  fh.write picture
end

driver.quit

# Resizes the window only to the viewable area, as a result,
# it captures the viewable area only
```

**SOLUTION 3 (Ruby- watir gem):**

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X'
b.screenshot.save("picture.png")

# Issues: does not capture the entire page
```

**SOLUTION 4 (Ruby - Single element capturing)**

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.get'https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X'

driver.manage.window.maximize
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('some_id').scrollIntoView();")
driver.save_screenshot "picture3.png"

# Problem: captures the element, which I need, but only if its size is less than
# the viewable area
```

**SOLUTION 5 (Ruby - Zooming)**

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.get 'https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X'

driver.manage.window.maximize
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)'")
#driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '50%'") <-- transform works better than zoom

driver.save_screenshot "picture3.png"

#Issues: works, but not for very long pages, in addition it may change the layout
# (some elements may start to overlap each other)
# Also I am not sure how to calculate the value of the parameter for scale
# for very long pages
```

**SOLUTION 6 - (Ruby - Headless Chrome Resizing)**

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

driver.get "https://some_very-very_long_page_on_website_X"

width  = driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,document.body.offsetWidth,document.documentElement.clientWidth,document.documentElement.scrollWidth,document.documentElement.offsetWidth);")
height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,document.body.offsetHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight,document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.offsetHeight);")

driver.manage.window.resize_to(width+2000, height+2000) # <-- if I do not have +2000, page looks squished
                                                        # the greater the number, the greater the quality
                                                        # but also the more white space is around the page
                                                        # and the picture is heavier
driver.manage.window.maximize

sleep 5             # <--- required waiting for page loading 
driver.save_screenshot "full.png"

# One of the best approaches, but it is not clear to me how to calculate 
# the parameters for resize_to
```

Tools/Technologies:

- selenium-webdriver (3.12.0)
- ChromeDriver 2.40

Comment: You're running into a limitation of the WebDriver spec - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#screen-capture - which defines the area of the screen when taking a screenshot as "the top-level browsing context’s initial viewport".  WebDriver also specifies a method for taking a picture of a specific element but that doesn't appear to be made available through `selenium-webdriver` yet, and I'm not sure whether or not Chrome/chromedriver have implemented it yet or not (and would still be limited by current size of the window)

Comment: You can capture the full screenshot with Firefox, but Chrome just grabs the visible area.  To capture the full page screenshot on Chrome you have to invoke the dev-tools.  I have the code in python if you want I can post it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199076/take-full-page-screen-shot-in-chrome-with-selenium has what you need I think

Comment: I follow your Solution 6, Can you please assist me to take full page screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using Firefox and the [`"webdrivers"`](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers) gem, which installs `"selenium-webdriver"` as a dependency:

```
require "webdrivers/geckodriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get("https://openai.com/api/")
File.binwrite("screenshot.png", driver.screenshot_as(:png, full_page: true))
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [watir-screenshot-stitch gem](https://github.com/samnissen/watir-screenshot-stitch) to do exactly what you want:

```rb
require 'watir-screenshot-stitch'
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/570"
b.base64_geckodriver # => returns a base64-encoded full page screenshot.
```