# Can anyone suggest how to take screenshot of full webpage using ruby selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I want to capture full webpage screenshot in chrome browser using ruby selenium. I am using Rspec testing framework. `save_screenshot` method captures screenshot only for visible area. 
I have gone through the following link,

[How to take a screenshot of a full browser page and its elements using selenium-webdriver/capybara in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865148/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-full-browser-page-and-its-elements-using-selenium)

But I don't want to use window resizing or watir gem. Is there any other way or gem to achieve same.

Comment: not sure it helps you but IE driver is actually good for this.  It'll take the whole page as screenshot.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/elcamino/5f562564ecd2fb86f559

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, I will check this out.

Comment: @TapasMahato you can use gem for save screenshot - https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#driver-configuration, where you can change preferences for size screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use https://github.com/samnissen/watir-screenshot-stitch where

- Directly employing geckodriver's new full page screenshot functionality (only on Firefox).
- Screenshot stitching, paging down a given URL by the size of the viewport, capturing screenshots and adjoining them.
- Employing a bundled html2canvas script against the page to generate a png from a canvas element.

2) or use native instrument for your OS - https://paulhammond.org/webkit2png
In code will look like this
`webkit2png https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728482/can-anyone-suggest-how-to-take-screenshot-of-full-webpage-using-ruby-selenium`

where:
- main command - `webkit2png`
- link page - `all else`

Answer (score 0):

It's old question, but it doesn't hurt to post this. Use Scrot to take screenshot, and later make gif. Since OP only want screenshots, command would be:

```
require 'screenscrot'
@screen = ScreenScrot.new
@screen.capture(:all)
```

On linux:

```
sudo apt install scrot -y && gem install screenscrot
```

Comment: Will this work with a headless browser?