# Taking Full Screenshot using WATIR

Tags: watir

I found an answer here in Java selenium binding for taking a full screenshot(Link is given below), How can I write the same in WATIR?

[Take full page screenshot in Chrome with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199076/take-full-page-screenshot-in-chrome-with-selenium/45201692#45201692)

Comment: Looks like that answer is from 2017, so it might not work anymore. I remember someone worked on a gem for this, but I haven't tried it myself. I believe it was https://github.com/samnissen/watir-screenshot-stitch.

Comment: Okay I will try `watir-screenshot-stitch` gem and let you know