# Change website viewport programmatically like shortcuts "ctrl+" "ctrl-" in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, viewport, meta

I want to change viewport programmatically using javascript like shortcuts: `CTRL + '+'` and `CTRL + '-'` in Chrome Browser.

Is it possible to do it only through the meta tag? Or is there a better solution?

Primary goal for this task: simulate `CTRL + '+'` and `CTRL + '-'` (like in Chrome Browser) in mobile devices by *pinch gesture* and in all browser (well, at least in Safari and Chrome).

Comment: The question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847432/zoom-body-browser

Comment: The proposed solutions are not exactly what I need. @Fawad the answers  from this link increaze zoom and add scrolls and this is not the effect like press ctrl + in Chrome (thats change viewport and fit in window). The answer by torazaburo closest to me, but I need the support of other browsers

Comment: If you need support of other browsers, then change the title of your post so it does not mention Chrome. In any case, this is bad practice. Zooming is something the **user** should be in complete control of.

Comment: @torazaburo in Chrome refer to shortcuts not to browser compatibility