# How can we achieve browser zoom in and zoom out in playwright?

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright, playwright-test

Need to find a way to zoom browser in and out during an e2e test run. Below code does not work.

```
await page.keyboard.down('Control');
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    await page.keyboard.press('+');
  }
  await page.keyboard.up('Control');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set this with Javascript:

```
 await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.body.style.zoom=1.0;
        });
```

Set the value to the required zoom:

- `1.0` is 100%
- `1.1` is 110%
- and so on

I don't have things installed to test this but let me know if you hit any issues and I'll look again.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get it with any of the ways above, I got it this way here

```
page.evaluate("document.body.style.zoom=2.0")
```

2.0=200%

Answer (score 0):

can be useful for you :

```
let zoom: 0.1;
let zoomLevel = 1;
zoomLevel += zoom;
document.getElementById("canvasDivContainer").offsetWidth == document.getElementById("canvasDivContainer").offsetWidth - 1000;
$('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
```

Answer (score 0):

A small change to the above answer as zoom property didn't exist. Got this working using transform property

```
 await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.75)'
})
```