# I need to scale an entire website down to 80%

Tags: css

I just built out a website for a client, based on the Photoshop files they sent me, and they came back and told me that somehow the PSDs were 125% the size they were supposed to be, and that they need be to shrink everything to 80% of what it is now.

I figure I'm going to need to re-cut all the images, but I would rather not rewrite the CSS so I'm exploring alternatives.

Currently, all values are in pixels. I'm wondering if I should try to find a script that would take all the pixel values and multiply by .8, or if I should use a px to em converter and then set the base size in the html tag to 80%, or if there is better way to fix this problem.

Comment: Whatever you do... id make sure you charge them double whatever you estimated for slicing and layout.

Comment: you definitely don't need to re-cut all images. When you open the image in photoshop, go to File -> Save for Web & Devices. In the opening screen you can set the image size to 80%. Save it, image resized.

Comment: Tell them to stand farther away from their monitors.

Comment: This could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css

Comment: lol @ j08691. SpaceBeers, I saw that but it didn't answer the question, really, except to say that Jon Tan did it, but it doesn't totally explain how. I will view the source on his site and see what I can learn from that.

Comment: How big is this CSS, really? Seems like a few choice Find/Replace commands in a good text editor would solve the problem.  Can you post the CSS?

Comment: The stylesheet is almost 1000 lines of code. Should I put it in pastebin?

Answer (score 44):

Ugly css hack alert! :D

```
html {
    zoom: 0.8; /* Old IE only */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

#### Update

It appears latest **Chrome** and **IE10** supports (and applies) *both* `zoom` and `transform` at the same time, scaling it twice, so I recommend only using `zoom` when testing old IE browsers.

Comment: +1 for quick n dirty fix that will work, sometimes that's really needed. The downside is that often, these quick fixes once applied tend to stay there "as long as it works", so "charge them double" suggestion seems best to me. But this is cool:)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. This wasn't really meant as a serious answer - but I do use this as a nice method to see how a site will look and/or work at another size :)

Comment: Beware, using scale transforms can cause problems with js based/pixelbased interaction types such as draggable and order. I'm working on a similar issue and have thusfar noticed some of those still work just fine when using em units, but not with scale transforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-size the page inside of an iframe that is at 80% width. You would need to remove the borders and turn scrolling of but it should work.

Tutorial here
[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

I haven't tried it but it seems like it could possibly be sketchy as far a browser compatibility and bugs if you ask me. just thought i would pass it along