# Scale down a webpage to 90%

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

When you press `Ctrl`+`-` on any browser, the page scales down to 90% of it's original size. I need to replicate that, and open my webpage at 90% of it's original by default, instead of 100% because it looks nicer at 90%.

I tried the most common approach as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036927/i-need-to-scale-an-entire-website-down-to-80), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668635/zoom-out-whole-website-using-jquery-or-css), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css), all of which basically tell you to add this block of code in your `css`.

```
html
{
    zoom: 0.9; /* Old IE only */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

The problem with this is that it creates a gap on the left and the right sides, as well as a huge gap on the top, which aren't present when you manually reduce the size by doing a `ctrl`+`-`.

This is what happens when I use the above mentioned code - notice the gaps on the left, right, top.
[image: This is what happens when I use the above mentioned code]

While this is what I want - this is what happens when you do a `ctrl`+ `-` manually in your browser.
[image: While this is what I want - this is what happens when you do a ctrl -.]

How do I go about this?

EDIT: As Jonathon said in the comments, if my page looks nicer at 90%, I should have designed it to be that way instead of having to scale down. The problem was that I'm using [this default template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/business-casual/), and I just prefer it at 90% over the full 100%.

Comment: Might not be what you want to hear, but if your page "looks nicer" at 90%, you should design it to look that way at 100%. You shouldn't really monkey with users' preferences in that way.

Comment: Haha @Jonathan, true. But now that I'm using this standard template - http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/business-casual/ and I like how it looks at 90% over 100%.
Any idea on how I should proceed?

Comment: @RandomlyNamedUser You need to modify the template. You're very unlikely to get an exact match by trying to manually scale stuff - the browser rendering is what'll be changing when you scale the output. You really need to go through the CSS and make it match the 90%

Comment: just using html{zoom:.9} seems to be working! (although zoom is ie specific and transform is the new one)

Comment: @radiant, thanks, it is :) But that will work only on chrome and IE and I need to make my code browser independent.

Comment: test in ie if that works too? also play with "transform" property. IMHO, it would best to update css where it needed to be browser independent than trying a messy hack,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use/convert to relative units in your CSS.  Either % or em or rem.

Then at the body level you can set an absolute size that results in the relative measures recalculating to what you want.

If you use em or ex exclusively:
You declare font-size: 90% for body and you'll be able to adjust on the fly.

It all comes down to the units you choose and making them relative will allow you the kind of freedom you are looking for now.

Comment: Be warned that em based media queries will not utilize your set base size, but rather the base size set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can compensate this gaps with margin-top:-50px; for specific elements.