# Make default zoom css

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, default

So my problem is fairly simple.
When I started to develop my website my default zoom level on my Firefox browser turned out to be, well, less than 100%. (Maybe 70%)
Which means that what I have designed so far is actually in zoomed out mode, which in turn means that my users or web visitors will see something that looks very zoomed in when they look at it with 100% mode.
This can easily be solved by holding Ctrl and scrolling you mouse wheel twice. Obviously though I can't encourage people to do that.

So,

Is there some function or property in either HTML, CSS or Javascript than can set the default zoom level to zoomed out?

Comment: That's not a solution to the problem. Design your site for 100% zoom.

Comment: Right, how can it be possible to do a whole site without noticing...I mean as soon as you set a font-size you notice!

Comment: Does a window displaying my current zoom level appear when setting a font-size?

Comment: No but browser default is 16px. If you know how 16px font-size looks like then you can tell you're not at 100% zoom.

Comment: Well my site will have to due. I don't want to redo it and have now learned an important lesson for my next websites.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, especially for presenting an initial view to a user with a small or oddly proportioned screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I would highly recommend to create your website again !!!***

Does it help ?

```
body { zoom: 3; -moz-transform: scale(3); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css)

Comment: I did help but it had some side effects. I will not use it.

Comment: It's a nice hack but trust **Jashwant** don't use it. Just make your website work at 100% or start over again.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome can display initial zoom levels such as

```
HTML { 
zoom:90%;
}
```

which would by itself zoom the entire page not the initial browser zoom level, this works like scaling, but it's not compatible with either firefox or safari or my guess. The rest of explorers.

GL

Answer (score -3):

Nop, you can't. That's a browser feature.