# zoom of webpage using HTML tags or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to set the zoom of webpage using HTML tags or javascript. I need to render a webpage on Internet explorer 9 with 85% zoom property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default zoom for web page programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469067/set-default-zoom-for-web-page-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of Javascript; simple example

`document.body.style.zoom="85%"`

or CSS:

```
body {
  zoom: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

document.body.style.zoom = "85%";