# How do you debug a discrepancy between computed property and the css property (e.g. div width)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

Specifically, I'm wondering how this can happen (from Chrome Developer Tools):

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools]

My understanding is that it is telling me that the CSS says to make the width 1000px, but the browser decided to make it 985px. How can I track down the root cause of the discrepancy?

I see the same thing in Safari Web Inspector. Specifically, the width value under Rules is 1000px:

[image: Safari Web Inspector rules shows width of 1000px]

while under Computed, the width is 985px:

[image: Safari Web Inspector computed shows width of 985px]

In case it matters, this particular issue is showing up for a div element.

Comment: Which Chrome version is this?

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Comment: Same as mine. But your pane looks completely different compared to mine (on linux). Does this also "happen" after restarting the browser? Have you installed plugins, does it "happen" when disabling them? Why have you tagged the post with [tag:safari-web-inspector] (you might remove it, if this Q is not related to Safari)?

Comment: Yes, it still happens after restarting the browser.

Yes, it still happens after disabling all Chrome extensions (which I assume is the same thing as "plugins").

Note that the first screenshot in my post is from Chrome, but the second and third are from Safari Web Inspector, hence, the tag. Maybe you are comparing your pane to my screen shots from Safari.

Comment: I've only seen this when the browser is zoomed (which Chrome can store between sessions). Under view, is Chrome set to "Actual Size"? Apparently you can set a zoom level with css, which might cause this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469067/set-default-zoom-for-web-page-programmatically

Comment: @cjspurgeon Yes, in Chrome, under View, it is set to Actual Size.