# css layout get distorted when zoom in

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Page adjust according to screen resolution like stackoverflow**
problem with **zooming** and **css layout** get **distorted** when zoom in. i'm new in css and first and very big problem i am facing is that when i zoom in or out page get distorted. i want to do something like my page fits every resolution. please give me such solution that i can **apply on whole page** including body and footer

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="head">
        <div id="head_back">
        <b id="logo">LOGO</b>
        <div id="nav">
            <b>2000</b>
            <b>2001</b>
            <b>2002</b>
            <b>2004</b>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{width:100%; background-color:red; overflow:auto; margin:0; padding:0;}
#head
{
    width:100%; height:100px; 
    color:#902df3;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    left:-7.8px;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    padding-right:17px;

}
#head #head_back
{
    position:absolute;
    line-height:90px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#999; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
#head #logo
{
    font-size:46px;
    position:absolute;  
}
#head #nav
{
    font-size:26px;
    position:absolute;
    left:60%;   
}
body html
{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: That's normal. Browser zoom sucks.

Comment: Are you talking about zooming or different screen sizes?

Comment: different screen sizes @aldux

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have a viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0"/>
```

Then you can use media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  ...
}
```

Check out this good resource on media queries: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Answer (score 0):

You can try messing with the css zoom feature or changing your units see this post for more help

[How can I scale an entire web page with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css)

If you are just trying to make it so your site looks different on mobile,tablets or desktops your best off using media queries in CSS and styling each one by a defined min-device-width.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Positioning is one of my least favorite aspects of web design.  Unfortunately, it also happens to be rather important.

Since there wasn't a link or anything for us to replicate the issue and verify with certainty what the problem is my answer will be mainly conjecture.

The *most likely* cause of your issue is due to the mixing of the absolute and relative positioning of your elements.  The relative elements *should* change when the the browser size is changed / zoomed.  Absolutely positioned elements would not.

One of the easier-to-follow guides out there:
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

I would also suggest installing the Firefox plug-in "Web Developer" and "Firebug".  These tools will allow you to modify the css settings on-the-fly to test what may actually be causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS code `min-width` for your body or your desired div.
Example:

```
body
{
    min-width: 1366px;
}
```

You can refer to this webpage for a better comprehension of the code above: [The MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

Hope this helped.