# Change the body's property "zoom" value in external css file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the value of the zoom property which I have in a external css file on the body selector. This zoom is set to 100% and is general for all HTML documents that has the css file linked in. What I want to do is:
I have this a link in my HTML document.

```
<a onClick="zoom('80%')">80%</a>
```

The javascript function is this one:

```
function zoom(zoom)
{
    $("a").click(function()
    {
        $('body').css('zoom','80%');
    }); 

}
```

What I want this to do is, by clicking the link, it will call the function and sending in 80% into the function. What I then want the function to do, is to go into my external css and replace 100% with 80%:

```
body                                                                        
{
    zoom: 100%;

}
```

I don't really know how to do this, so I'm asking you guys! This is a part of my final task for the webdesign course that I'm taking, so I would really want this to work!

Comment: Um, why? I mean, sure, it's possible using `styleSheets` collection and a lot of hacking around, but... why?

Comment: What effect are you looking for from this?  Do you want it to make the change permanent, or maybe affect all visitors?

Comment: The whole point of *cascading* style sheets is that you can override styles easily -- far more easily than going in and replacing what's in the stylesheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scale an entire web page with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css)

Comment: I'm not sure but, have you tried it on  your line 5$('body').css('zoom', zoom); ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to do this: [How can I scale an entire web page with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css)

That's done with javascript like this, but with the proper style taging:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.width = "80%";
document.getElementById('image').style.height = "80%";
```

Comment: I don't see how that will help me, since I don't want to change an ID. I want to go inside the my external CSS file and change the body seclector's property value to 80% when clicking on that link. The result of having the 80% will be that my website will hav decreased in zoom, helping people with low screen resolution to adjust the page to their needs.

Comment: You don't change an Id, you change the property of the ID.  Is what you're asking how do you chance the stretch of the image to a smaller size?  If so, you can do it directly from the style tag.  You can also do everything in percentage, and the page will scale however you want it to.

Comment: No that's not the case. When I change the zoom in the selctor "body", the ENTIRE website will zoom out. That's what I want to achieve so that users with smaller screen size than 1080p will be able to see the entire site without having the need to to use the scrollbars in x/y direction

Comment: I think what you mean is how do you do key pressing of ctrl + "+".  Here is the key pressing simulator I've found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events