# Webpage adjust zoom display

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I was toying with zoom display on my web browser ( ctrl + scroll ) and i found that my website looks a lot better in zoom 90% compared to the default zoom 100%.

So i was wondering is they anyway to get my website on the 90% aspect without changing one by one all the Css stylesheets ?

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: Try css's zoom element. Or `transform: scale(90%);` Apply it to anything :P In your case: the body.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css

Comment: @IlijaLončarević Ah thanks guys, sorry didn't realize they was already a clear answer to this problem ...

Comment: @ForceMagic thanks wasn't expecting such an easy solution !

Answer (score 0):

Use the transform css property:

```
transform: scale(90%);
```

...or just use zoom:

```
zoom: 0.9;
```

Make sure to append `-webkit-` and `-moz-` and `-o-` for maximum compatibility in transform & scale!