# Playing with HTML zoom in CSS

Tags: css

Hello StackFlow community,

I wanted to zoom all the elements of my website for bigger resolutions

So I wrote this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1368px) {
    html {zoom: 110%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1640px) {
    html {zoom: 120%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1846px) {
    html {zoom: 135%;}
}
```

It works great generally, except some minor details that do not behave as I would like.

One of them is the plugin MailMunch : Scrollbox (highlighted in green in my image)
It acquired a **huge shift** (represented by the red arrow)

In default mode, it was displaying in **bottom right corner**, now it goes way to the top and it's impossible to read the whole of it.

[image]

Bad news for that: I can't play with the CSS since I am in free mode, and it's a dynamic element I can't force custom CSS through my theme.

Would you have any advice regarding this issue?

Either playing with my code on selectors HTML, either playing somehow on this scrollbox?

URL is: https://osezrealiservosreves.com/esprit-critique-koober/

Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: So you installed a plugin on your own site? Why can't you fiddle with the css? You can just add your own styles which override the default styles, right?

Comment: Can you please show the code of the plugin you installed?

Comment: giorgio exactly this is a WordPress plugin, but I do not have custom CSS for this plugin in freemode.

Sometimes I can write custom CSS on my theme and act on the selectors of some plugins, but for this one I can't

Comment: There is no code for the plugin, it's just a WordPress plugin and I have no access to it in free mode. You can still see the plugin displaying at this URL: https://osezrealiservosreves.com/esprit-critique-koober/

Comment: _“Would you have any advice regarding this issue?”_ - only rather off-topic one … that this: _“I wanted to zoom all the elements of my website for bigger resolutions”_ is not the right approach to responsive websites to begin with.

Comment: It's worth noting that `zoom` is not the standard CSS property, it was a proprietary addition to CSS by Microsoft somewhere in the end of 90s and was then adopted by WebKit/Blink browser engines (with their own understanding how it should work). Firefox has never supported it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom#Browser_compatibility), and the CSS Device Adaptation spec draft allows it only for the `@viewport` rule, not for HTML elements.

Comment: Okay, then which other way could I have to do this "zoom effect" without using this property?

Comment: increase element widths/heights for bigger resolutions , basically change the css for elements you wish to look bigger

Comment: why not use transform: scale instead of zoom - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css#answer-17408949

Comment: yes but it would apply the transformation for the plugin scrollbox as well, so it does not resolve my issue