# How to set zoom on a element using Javascript on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, zooming

I can change a page element on Chrome using `zoom`

```js
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.zoom = 0.5
```

Looks like Firefox did not support `zoom`, when i run the same code nothing happens.

Im searching for how to use `zoom` on Firefox, and i got this code:

```js
document.getElementById("pane-side").style["-moz-transform"] = "scale(0.5)"
```

But the result was not what I expected:

[image]

Im trying to zoom out the element like on Chrome, any advice?

**-EDIT-**
The element I'm trying to zoom in is from the page `web.whatsapp.com`, the panel where show some contacts when you type something in the search (like on the chrome photo).

Comment: Its just style.transform not moz-transform

Comment: I got the same result using style.transform.

Comment: you should add a class to your element with transform: scale(1.2); transform-origin: 0 0; as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zoom` is not supported by FireFox.

Solutions below should work as you expect, only **adjust numbers for your needs**:

```
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.transform = "scale(0.5)";
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.transformOrigin = "left top";
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.width = "795px";
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.minHeight = "1700px";
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.alignSelf = "flex-start";
```

Or CSS version:

```
#pane-side {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 795px;
    min-height: 1700px;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Or eventually `<style>` element added with JS:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `
    #pane-side {
        transform: scale(0.5);
        transform-origin: left top;
        width: 795px;
        min-height: 1700px;
        align-self: flex-start;
    }
`;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not using this CSS property for a website in production,
the property *zoom* is a non-standard CSS property, originated from IE, unofficially proposed in May 2015 by Rossen Atanassov working at Microsoft.
It is unsafe to use since it will not work for every browser (and in my humble opinion, probably not going to be implemented). Unfortunately, this CSS property is not implemented in the Firefox Browser hence you are experiencing this issue.

I see that you already tried to use *transform: scale();* instead,
and the difference in your screenshot is due to the fact *zoom* affects the layout size of the elements, while *transform: scale();* does not.

You could try with the CSS at-rule @viewport, but keep in mind that this one was deprecated too (in 2020, here are the details: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4766) and probably doesn't work in Firefox either.
In your CSS file:

```
@viewport {
  zoom: 1
}
```

A zoom factor of 1 or 100% corresponds to no zooming. Larger values zoom in. Smaller values zoom out.

That being said, you could also try to set bigger the font size of the target element (to have a zoomed-in effect).
If this is not enough, you could try to find a good balance between those properties.
I'll do the CSS example that might scale up all the font sizes:

```
body {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   font-size: 150%; // or any other value that is bigger than the computed value
   padding: 20%; // optional spacing if some text is not visible because of the transform scale
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you?

```
zoom: 0.5;
-ms-zoom: 0.5;
-webkit-zoom: 0.5;
-moz-transform:  scale(0.5,0.5);
-moz-transform-origin: left center;
```

Comment: im not sure about how to use it, I tried: `document.getElementById("pane-side").zoom = 0.5;` and did not changed anything, also `document.getElementById("pane-side").style["-moz-transform"] = "scale(0.5,0.5)"`does the same as on the picture I post

Answer (score 0):

Both `-moz-transform` and `transform` should be supported in FF.

It could be because of the differences between `zoom` and `scale`.

`zoom` is applied pre-render and changes the layout sizing of the element.
`transform` is applied post-render and doesn't change the layout sizing

The easiest way to see this is with a div sized relative to a fixed element.
On `zoom`, everything inside the div will zoom in/out, but the div stays the same
On `scale`, everything 'zooms' in/out, including the div

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use CSS Variables Try this

```js
document.getElementById("pane-side").style.setProperty('--zoom', '0.5');
```

```css
        
*{
    transform: scale(var(--zoom));
}
```

```html
<h1 id="pane-side" >Firefox</h1>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("pane-side").style.setProperty('--zoom', '0.5');` return undefined, the other code I'm not sure how to use, I'm trying to change the zoom of an element of a page that's not mine

Comment: You must add the css

Comment: how do i add the css?

Comment: `<style>*{
    transform: scale(var(--zoom));
}</style>` add this code to between `<head>` and `</head>`

Comment: i did it but i got the same result as using `document.getElementById("pane-side").style["-moz-transform"] = "scale(0.5)"`, the page I'm trying to zoom is web.whatsapp.com, the panel where show you contacts when you search one number.

Comment: Then you can just press `ctrl` + `+` To zoom the webpage

Comment: im trying to zoom the element `pane-side` of the page and `not` the whole page, look at the picture I post above, and compare the difference of the  firefox/chrome zoom on the `pane-side element`

Comment: did you try this code ? `document.getElementById("pane-side").style["width"] = "75%";`