# Imitating mobile safari's default zoom

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, safari

If you open a web page that is not mobile-specific at all, say, http://dogpile.com , on an iPhone 4, mobile safari does some default zoom to show the entire page.

Does anyone know what logic it is they are actually doing, or how I can simulate this within an iFrame within any browser on a non-mobile device? Should I use a css zoom: on the iFrame document body?

EDIT: So from a NON mobile device browser, e.g. regular old safari, FF, or Chrome, I want to have an iFrame with the resolution of an iPhone and scale the page within the iframe the same way mobile safari does.

Comment: What browsers are you supporting?

Comment: WebKit browsers for now. And again, just to be clear since I know I wasn't before, I want to do this on a NON mobile device browser. See above edit in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math is based on the width of the `<body>` tag. If you don't have that you could just base in on a with of 980px which is web standard. Assuming this we can create the iframe and full size (980px wide) and then scale the iframe into place with css3. Example here [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Don't care about IE. Fresheyeball, thanks for the tip about body tag width...makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I know that your answer would tell mobile safari to scale the site, but I want to do this on a site within an iframe on any browser, not mobile safari. Should've mentioned that. I'm trying to imitate this scaling via CSS or some other method client-side.

Comment: I guess I'm still being vague. From a NON mobile device browser, e.g. regular old safari, FF, or Chrome, I want to have an iFrame with the resolution of an iPhone and scale the page within the iframe the same way mobile safari does.