# How could I have an iframe that shows the target page and all it's elements at 50% scale?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How could I have an iframe that shows the target page and all it's elements at 50% scale?

My first thought was trying to write a css scale property to the frame, but I'm not sure if you can write css to the contents of the frame.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the iframe point to the same domain as the parent, or another domain?

Comment: possibly `* { zoom: 0.5; }` though I'm not sure how `zoom` holds in regards to standards or compliance. (That also may only be an IE thing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/166160/1164491

Comment: @Cheery hrrm this doesn't seems to scale the actual contents of the frame, just the frame itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier then I thought...

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

$('#frame').css
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(.5)'
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(.5)'
    '-o-transform': 'scale(.5)'
```

Comment: You forgot `-ms-transform`. Don't diss Microsoft now that they've got their act in gear.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is in the same domain, you might be able to place this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href != top.location.href) {

   // the page is loaded inside an iframe so
   // Make everything 50% scale (I'm not sure what the code for that is in pure js)
   // With jQuery:

   $("*").css("zoom","50%");

} 
</script>
```

In the head of the page you are loading in the iframe.

If you're not using JQuery, this page

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/06/01/Javascript-Loop-through-all-elements-in-a-form.aspx

has a good example of how to loop through all the elements in a form without a library like JQuery.

Comment: Cool, I could see this working, how do I inject that code though? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the style only be applied on the body?

Comment: @Bergi Could be, i'm not 100% sure how the zoom attribute works

Comment: @fancy if you are using jquery, then put it between the <head></head> tags after you load jquery, if you're not using jquery, then anywhere int he head should work