# iframe zoom issue

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, zooming

I am attempting to get a cross-browser css zoom to work, but everything I have found here isn't working for me.

Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="themeframe">
<div class="themeframe-overlay"></div>
<iframe src="/index.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#themeframe{
position:relative;
width:520px;
height:400px;
margin-top: 20px;
border: none;
overflow: hidden;
}

#themeframe .themeframe-overlay{
position:absolute;
z-index:95;
left:0;top:0;
height:100%;width:100%;
background:#fff;
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}


#themeframe iframe {
width:1040px;
min-height: 800px;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.5);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
border: none;
}
```

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I have a 520 x 400 div that I want filled with a 50% scaled version of a webpage. As shown above, I have issues in IE, where the div/iframe is the correct size, but the webpage inside is 100%, NOT 50%. This is working in every other browser. If I add zoom:0.5; to the iframe css, it fixes it in IE, but breaks it in chrome.

I am having trouble getting this to work in IE, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all at the same time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, which at least worked for me. Part of this answer was used following the steps [found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

First, arrange your **HTML** like this (I'm bad at arranging code on this site):

```
<div id="themeframe">
    <iframe src="/index.php" id="frame" width="794" height="1550"></iframe >
</div>
```

Then **CSS** looks like this:

```
#themeframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:800px;
    height:850px;
    -ms-zoom: 0.75;
}


#frame {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: -300px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

The changes I'll point out are:

1. I wrapped the `iframe` in a `div` called `themeframe`
2. I gave the `iframe` an `id` so we could style it in CSS.
3. I used the `-ms-zoom` on the wrapping div of `themeframe` not within the `iframe`. This is because IE will scale the whole iframe to your set `zoom` size, not the content within it (which is what Chrome and Firefox do). It is also important to use `-ms-zoom` in the CSS and not simply `zoom` since Chrome will go crazy and pay attention to both `zoom` and `-webkit` if you don't make the `ms` distinction.

Hope this helps. It works for me in Chrome, FF and IE8.