# How to scale iframe contents on iPad

Tags: css, iframe, safari

I have successfully implemented the CSS to scale across browsers as previously shown (with add-ons and edits) in this thread:

[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

But now I find that it does not work in Safari on an iPad. Can anyone shed some light here? The working code I have is at http://gfx.com/example

Here is the current CSS...

```
#framewrap { width: 238px; height: 303px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#myframe { width: 990px; height: 1260px; overflow: hidden; z-index:10; }
#myframe {
    -ms-zoom: 0.24;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.24);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.24);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.24);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

The goal is to have the loaded webpage (iframe source) scale to the iframe.

Comment: Doesn't work in the latest Chrome either

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Using Iframes on Mobile Safari because there is a rendering bug that apple/web-kit has yet to fix.