# Zooming pdf files in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I would like to know how to zoom in on my pdf files in an iframe, with the default set at something like 200%.

I know that iframe, when used to view pdf files, has a zoom 'bar' that pops up, but I want to set the zoom by default so that users don't have to manually zoom. How do I achieve this?

My iframe asp.net code is:

```
<iframe id="pdfFrame" runat="server" style="height:375px;width:550px;" />
```

And code behind to view a pdf is:

```
pdfFrame.Attributes["src"] = "../pdfDocs.ashx?ID=" + index[i];
```

As you can see, I am using a handler, because my pdf is a varbinary in sql. No issues to pull anything out. My issue is the size of the file in the iframe.

I have tried to follow [resize the pdf in iframe](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?595599-resize-the-pdf-in-iframe) but note that I am not using a src in my iframe.
And I have looked at [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe/2224816#2224816) but that is not working.

I am using a master page and this aspx page is one of the content pages, so I would not like to modify the size of the pdf to clash with the master page's content.

How can I set the size? is it something in my handler? Or something in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its ok. I used a query string to get the id I needed, then redirected to another page with a bigger iframe, one that was not a part of the master page styling. 
then I loaded it and, got a bigger pdf