# How to scale the content of a frame

Tags: html, css, dom

I need to supervise some web page provided by several servers. 
I have made the following simple html code with a frameset:

```
     <frameset cols="25%,25%,25%,*" rows="50%,*" border="0">
        <frame src="http://server1/" />
        <frame src="http://server2/" />
        <frame src="http://server3/" />
        <frame src="http://server4/" />
        <frame src="http://server5/" />
        <frame src="http://server6/" />
    </frameset>
```

the page is auto-refreshed every 60s thanks to a "`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />`" in the header.

But, as I was forced to add 2 more servers recently, the content of each frame is not always enough readable (I can't see the interesting part any more without scrolling each frame).

I would like to "scale down" or "zoom out" the content of each frame. Despite some long research on Google, the only approaching solution I found, is this one : [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe) which unfortunately reduce the size of the frame not its content.

Is it possible ?

If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

give a try to [jQuery zoomer](http://dev.hubspot.com/blog/bid/89755/jQuery-Zoomer-Zoom-up-your-iFrames)
Not sure if it can apply to regular frames too, but it's worth trying.

Otherwise, consider some deeper jQuery usage by querying the servers and outputting their pages in a placeholder via ajax, also you might need to strip the <head> and body tags to prevent invalid code, not sure how a meta refresh will behave in that conditions or if the pages you'll load have scripts.

You could set the loading and autorefresh of the servers content with a simple function:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
jQuery("#server1").load('http://server1/').fadeIn("slow");
}, 60000);
```

and create divs with id="server1" server2 etc. as destinations.

Edit: **This will probably trigger cross-domain access restrictions**, so you'll need a proxy to dump locally the frames before pushing their contents in the "monitoring" page.