# Keeping pixel ratio but scaling size

Tags: html, css, asp.net, emulation

So I have this emulator that's created using asp.net.
The emulator uses and iframe at the size of the device.

However, on ipad the device size is way to big for the screen and I need to scale it.

Does anyone know how I can go abouts scaling this iPad but keeping the pixel ratio of an ipad?
Or if this is even at all possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you. I had same issue before and this worked.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 0):

You can use a padding-bottom trick to ensure any elements retain their ratio at variable widths.

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
}

iframe .child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The `56.25%` ensures the iframe will retain a 16:9 ratio, calculated by doing 9 / 16 * 100

Now you can change the iframe's width to whatever is appropriate for your layout.