# Iframe content is responsive but does not scale (or break) on mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, responsive-design

**Hi, I have searched everywhere for an answer to this:
(Any help would be greatly appreciated**
I have a responsive landing page which has / needs an Iframe inside which will display a website which is *also* responsive and has a *breaking point for mobile* atleast. 
On any browser it works and looks fine, but if you view it on mobile, the content does not *scale or respond* to wrapper width and *break* to become it's original mobile view. It only scales the entire page down, ie: Text, too small to read and site *within iFrame* doesn't break to *mobile view*.
 I need the content to break for mobile and adhere to it's own, original media queries. The surrounding page is fine and the wrapper is perfect.

Is there possibly some Javascript I could insert to make it work? Can I do this using plain css?

***Here is a link to the page:***

http://clients.foxps.com/lp/cps2.html

Notice; when scale width of browser, content of iframe breaks nicely BUT on mobile...not :(

***Here is a code snippet of my HTML & CSS(MOBILE MEDIA QUERY):***

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

html {
  max-height: 700px !important;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 200px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
}
body {
  max-height: 700px !important;
}
.media-logo {
  width: 264px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: none;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
}
.logo {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 264px;
  min-height: 220px;
}
/*Back button styling*/

header p {
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe;
  Font being rendered: Calibri;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 30pt;
}
header p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555
}
header p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.back-btn {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 18px 15px 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}
.back-link {
  padding: 25px 35px !important;
  background: #405FAE;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.back-link:hover {
  background: #2f447b;
  border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.back-link:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: #2E5481;
  border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
/*Back button styling*/

/*Wrapper styling begin*/

.rapper-yo {
  max-height: 750px !important;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5em 2em 2em 2em !important;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font: normal 100%/1.4 sans-serif;
  color: #515477;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1.5px solid #666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transition: transform .05s linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/*Wrapper styling end*/

.main {
  padding-top: 150px !important;
  top: 200px;
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 460px;
  margin: auto;
}
body > footer:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #555555;
}
center.foot {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 120px;
  border-bottom: #A1A2A2 solid 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #555555;
}
center.foot nav {
  margin: auto;
}
#social-icon {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
}
#social-icon .icons li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 0 3px;
  list-style: none;
}
.icons li a {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.icons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20 10 0 10;
  padding: 0;
}
.icons li {
  marging: auto;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.icons li a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.icons li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#social-icon {
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 1090;
  padding: 0 10 0 10;
}
#social-icon > ul.icons {
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 10 10 10 0;
}
ul > li > a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.social-linkdin > a {
  background: url(../img/linkdin-icon.svg) no-repeat;
  min-height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  min-width: 70px;
}
.social-twitter > a:nth-child(1) {
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 105px;
  padding: 0 10 0 10;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.social-facebook > a:nth-child(1) {
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 0 10 0 10;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.social-linkdin > a:nth-child(1) {
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
  padding: 0 10 0 10;
  margin: auto;
}
.social-twitter > a {
  background: url(../img/twitter-icon.svg) no-repeat;
  min-height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  min-width: 70px;
}
.social-facebook > a {
  background: url(../img/facebook-icon.svg) no-repeat;
  min-height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  min-width: 70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#social-icon .table {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 80px;
}
.icons li {
  padding: 0 5;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline;
}
#social-icon > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#copyright > div.right > p {
  padding: 12px 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 35pt;
  line-height: 32pt;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe;
  Font being rendered: Calibri;
  color: #999999;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
#copyright > div.left > p {
  padding: 12px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 35pt;
  line-height: 32pt;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe;
  Font being rendered: Calibri;
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
#copyright > div.right {
  width: 62%;
  float: right;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}
#copyright > div.left {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}
#copyright {
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 120px;
  background: #555555;
}
#copyright.target {
  min-height: 130px;
}
center {
  top: 60px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/Fox-favicon.png" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) ' href='css/mobile.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) ' href='css/mobile-land.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:900px)(orientation: landscape) ' href='css/normal.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) ' href='css/normal.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen  and (max-width: 2200px)' href='css/main.css' />


  <title>Fox Parrack Singapour</title>





  <!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->
</head>

<body>
  <header class="logo">
    <div class="main-logo">
      <a href="http://www.foxps.com" target="_blank">
        <img class="media-logo" src="img/fox-logo.png" width="130" height="110" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="back-btn">
      <p valign="bottom">
        <a href="http://clients.foxps.com/lp/" class="back-link">
          < Back</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>


  <div class="rapper-yo">
    <iframe src="http://marketing2.xmpie.net/CPS/Joe.Finn?section=orange" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <center class="foot">
      <nav id="social-icon">
        <div class="table">
          <ul class="icons">
            <li class="social-twitter">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/FoxParrack" alt="Follow us on Twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="social-facebook">
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/FoxParrackSingapour/165269563545341" alt="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="social-linkdin">
              <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/271071?trk=prof-exp-company-name" alt="Follow us on linkedin"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </center>


    <div id="copyright" class="target">
      <div class="left">
        <p><small><a href="http://foxps.com/cookies-policy" >Cookies Policy</a></small>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p align="right"><small>Copyright &#169; 2015 Fox Parrack Singapour. All rights reserved.</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </footer>

  <blockquote>&nbsp;</blockquote>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

[Stack Overflow Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I have already tried this, doesn't seem to work in this case, it just makes the dimensions even smaller.