# How to scale video size to fit iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://example.com/embed-k59o3sirni24-640x318.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=338></IFRAME>

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Problem: `640x318` in src.

Any workaround with css jquery...

i need to scale video to size of iframe, and iframe is 100% of div where iframe belongs to.

Comment: can you explain in little more details and also put a fiddle.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous but probably the tool on the following page can be useful, [embedresponsively](http://embedresponsively.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the behavior of the content of the frame.

Since the dimension of the video is part of the URL, I am assuming the video is just fixed size.

You could try however to scale (css zoom property) the content of the frame using the answers to this question, but there seem to be a lot of browser differences to be considered:

[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)