# Setting an iframe's inner html5 object width to 100%

Tags: css, html, object, iframe, width

I'm attempting to make a html5 object within an iframe set to 100% width to no avail. At the moment the width of the inner html5 object overflows the iframes boundaries and doesn't fit correctly so I'm trying to constrain it. I've used code like so:

```
#quote iframe object {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there any way of targeting an inner html5 element easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't target elements inside an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access inside the iframe. Iframe is like new browser window. You have no access from one window to another.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't target specific items in the iframe and size them, you can scale the iframe as a whole to the appropriate size. Perhaps that is what you need instead, if your iframe's inner objects are overflowing its boundaries. Check out this quesiton: [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe).