# how to zoom content in iframe to fit my page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I need to place this iframe inside my page, I need to zoom it (to be smaller)

the original page is `http://palweather.ps/temps/days/forecast/120`

I tried the following code (I added `#zoom=75` after the link but it didn't work)

```
    <iframe border="0" frameborder="0" height="1300" name="map" src="http://palweather.ps/temps/days/forecast/120#zoom=75" style="width: 100%;" >Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 5):

This works well after for hours trying to get it to work in IE8, 9, and 10 here's what worked for me.

//html

```
<div class="wrap">
    This version works on FF 26, Chrome 32, Opera 18, and IE 9-11. 
    <iframe class="frame" src="http://time.is"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <iframe class="frame" src="http://www.knowledgecity.com/activities/BUS1058-008/BUS1058-008.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

//javascript

```
.wrap {
    width: 320px;
    height: 192px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.frame {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 786px;
    border: 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    transform: scale(0.25);

    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AwokeKnowing/yy8yb/