# Load template to iframe and force desktop CSS only

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a responsive `iframe` where I load a bootstrap 3 HTML template. I am building the ability for a user to customise the template by changing colors / fonts.

What I want to accomplish is keeping the HTML and CSS in large screen mode and scale the image down with the size of the `iframe` responding to browser changes.

Using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/) I have succeeded in creating the `iframe` responsive in my page. But right now its contents will change to mobile CSS on the smaller page / `iframe` sizes.

Is it possible to fix the viewport of the `iframe` content to a medium to large screen? Or perhaps a responsive CSS class that scales the content with the `iframe` changes?

In my example, the content is in A4 page format, so I created a really small transparent png with A4 ratio per the suggestion in the example.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 template-preview-container">
        <div class="h_iframe">
            <img class="ratio" src="/img/app/iframe-background.png"/>
            <iframe src="http://my/template/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're generating the iframe, so in the actual html of the iframe page, can you set a min-width on the body element? This should cause the iframe to have a horizontal scrollbar if the iframe width is less than that min-width

Comment: Hi @ShamSUP thanks for the response. I am trying to achieve keeping the contents in A4 mode and scale it to fit the iframe viewport. So on a mobile, the iframe would contain the desktop layout, just shrunk in size.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3131624/3101532) help at all? I do think that you'll have to set a min-width on the body element still, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi ShamSUP, it certainly has kept me busy for 2 hours with no luck. I want to stay oin the desktop view and change its zoom to keep  the width of the iframe and its contents to the width of the page. I have managed to get the JS code to work on window resize but it still changes to mobile at a point. Thanks, I will keep trying.