# IFRAME - how to force desktop view?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, responsive

I am loading remote content in an iframe. Since the iframe width is smaller than the full width of the html doc, the mobile view of the site is displayed. Is there a way to force the desktop view? E.g. by "fooling" the CSS of the remote site into thinking that the width of the iframe is larger?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is something like what is request here:
[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

In the comments to **Ixs** answer is the link with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/EEgTx/show/

What you need to do is to change the zoom of the page inside the iframe to trick media queries, so the idea is that a `1000px` width iframe with zoom of `0.8` will trigger a `~1200px` media query. You change the values to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Use scale and translate in an iframe:**
Unfortunately, it seems that there is not a simple method to set the iframe tag as desktop view, but you can use scale and translate in iframe as following to have the desktop view of a URL in a part of your webpage.

```html
<div style="width:300px;height: 220px;direction: rtl;background-color:red;">
<iframe src="https://iransitemap.ir" style="transform: scale(0.28,0.28) translate(1258px,-865px);width: 1000px;height: 700px;border-radius: 50px;" ></iframe>
</div>
```